# Create new list with positive elements

Tags: python, list, loops, python-3.x

I am trying to create a new list inside a looping (without change the name) which will cut all the negative or zero elements, eventually changing its length. Who is the fastest way to do that? I have lost the last days trying to do...

Comment: Google should provide several answers.  I would start by reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013449/list-filtering-list-comprehension-vs-lambda-filter

Comment: `[i for i in original_list if i > 0]`

Answer (score 3):

Try using filter:

`newlist = filter(lambda a: a>0, [1,2,3])`

or

`[i for i in original_list if i > 0]` *(as mentioned in comments above)*

Comment: Yea. There should be no problem in python3.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a religion in python, use lambda or not, but for this simple example I wouldn't use filters.

I personally would prefer a solution with lists and sets:

```
a = [1,2,-1,0,-1,...] # some list
for i in set(a):
    if (i <= 0): 
         while (a.count(i)>0): a.remove(i)
```

Comment: That won't work, aside from the performance problems: if there are two `-1` elements, you'll only remove one of them.

Comment: @DSM Ok the first version wouldn't work, since `a.remove(x)` removes only one element at once, but why do you think lambda functions perform better?

Comment: The problem with your code isn't lambda/no lambda (my preferred solution is the listcomp one).  The problem is that you have to (1) scan through the entire list every time you find a negative element, and (2) every time you remove an element from the middle of `a` you have to make a new list, which is very slow.  Try both the listcomp solution and yours on, say, `a = range(-10**4, 10**4)`.  Your approach will take several thousand times longer.