# Finding intersection/difference between python lists

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have two python lists:

```
a = [('when', 3), ('why', 4), ('throw', 9), ('send', 15), ('you', 1)]

b = ['the', 'when', 'send', 'we', 'us']
```

I need to filter out all the elements from a that are similar to those in b. Like in this case, I should get:

```
c = [('why', 4), ('throw', 9), ('you', 1)]
```

What should be the most effective way?

Comment: Why not use the method intersection? It works off sets but you can probably make it work better ;)

Comment: Why is this question tagged with numpy? Do you need a numpy solution?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A list comprehension will work.

```
a = [('when', 3), ('why', 4), ('throw', 9), ('send', 15), ('you', 1)]
b = ['the', 'when', 'send', 'we', 'us']
filtered = [i for i in a if not i[0] in b]

>>>print(filtered)
[('why', 4), ('throw', 9), ('you', 1)]
```

Comment: this is a much elegant way of doing it while keeping the lists as lists, and not treating them as dicts...thank you for the help.

Comment: You should convert `b` to a `set` if you are using the `in` operator. It changes the lookup time from linear to constant, which will make a huge difference when `b` is a long list. So, `c = set(b)` and then `filtered = [i for i in a if not i[0] in c]`. Note that `b` became `c` in the last line. Even on this short list with 5 items, it results in a 25% speed improvement for me. With a longer list (100 items in `b`), it results in a 90% speed improvement.

Answer (score 5):

A list comprehension should work:

```
c = [item for item in a if item[0] not in b]
```

Or with a dictionary comprehension:

```
d = dict(a)
c = {key: value for key in d.iteritems() if key not in b}
```

Comment: Did you want `{key: value for key, value in d.iteritems() if key not in b}`?

Answer (score 2):

`in` is nice, but you should use sets at least for `b`. If you have numpy, you could also try `np.in1d` of course, but if it is faster or not, you should probably try.

```
# ruthless copy, but use the set...
b = set(b)
filtered = [i for i in a if not i[0] in b]

# with numpy (note if you create the array like this, you must already put
# the maximum string length, here 10), otherwise, just use an object array.
# its slower (likely not worth it), but safe.
a = np.array(a, dtype=[('key', 's10'), ('val', int)])
b = np.asarray(b)

mask = ~np.in1d(a['key'], b)
filtered = a[mask]
```

Sets also have have the methods `difference`, etc. which probably are not to useful here, but in general probably are.

Comment: +1 for numpy. Didn't saw your answer before posting my answer. `in1d` is faster than the list comprehension for larger data sets by a factor of 2.

Answer (score 2):

As this is tagged with `numpy`, here is a numpy solution using [`numpy.in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) benchmarked against the list comprehension:

```
In [1]: a = [('when', 3), ('why', 4), ('throw', 9), ('send', 15), ('you', 1)]

In [2]: b = ['the', 'when', 'send', 'we', 'us']

In [3]: a_ar = np.array(a, dtype=[('string','|S5'), ('number',float)])

In [4]: b_ar = np.array(b)

In [5]: %timeit filtered = [i for i in a if not i[0] in b]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 778 ns per loop

In [6]: %timeit filtered = a_ar[-np.in1d(a_ar['string'], b_ar)]
10000 loops, best of 3: 31.4 us per loop
```

So for 5 records the list comprehension is faster.

However for large data sets the numpy solution is twice as fast as the list comprehension:

```
In [7]: a = a * 1000

In [8]: a_ar = np.array(a, dtype=[('string','|S5'), ('number',float)])

In [9]: %timeit filtered = [i for i in a if not i[0] in b]
1000 loops, best of 3: 647 us per loop

In [10]: %timeit filtered = a_ar[-np.in1d(a_ar['string'], b_ar)]
1000 loops, best of 3: 302 us per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
a = [('when', 3), ('why', 4), ('throw', 9), ('send', 15), ('you', 1)]

b = ['the', 'when', 'send', 'we', 'us']

c=[]

for x in a:
    if x[0] not in b:
        c.append(x)
print c
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/zW7mzY

Comment: Backwards: the OP wants `c` to contain the things _not_ in `b`

Comment: This seems to be the "`c++` way", not the "`python` way" ;)

Comment: @tohecz c++ doesn't support `in` operator.

Comment: @Arpit No, but essentially uses loops for container manipulations, which Python essentially _ought not to_.

Comment: Im still rooting for intersection! :]

Answer (score 0):

**Easy way**

```
a = [('when', 3), ('why', 4), ('throw', 9), ('send', 15), ('you', 1)]
b = ['the', 'when', 'send', 'we', 'us']
c=[] # a list to store the required tuples 
#compare the first element of each tuple in with an element in b
for i in a:
    if i[0] not in b:
        c.append(i)
print(c)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use filter:

```
c = filter(lambda (x, y): False if x in b else True, a)
```

Comment: **-1**: If you're using `False if .. else True` or `True if ... else False` then you're doing it wrong

Comment: Wrong according to a certain "Python style", or wrong due to some other reason?

Comment: `X in Y` itself is a boolean statement in python

Comment: Wrong in the same way as `if x > 1 == True:`, `if (x > 1 == True) == True:` or `if condition: b = True\n else: b = False`

Comment: @RahulBanerjee `False if ... else True` is needlessly complex and hard to read - just do `lambda (x, y): x not in b`. Also, this causes a syntax error in Python 3 - you would have to do `lambda x: x[0] not in  b` because the form of argument unpacking you use is no longer part of the language.

Comment: @Eric: I think you are complaining that it is hard-to-read, but I find it easy to read.

Comment: @lvc: Your answer makes sense (i.e., this syntax is illegal in Python 3). Thanks!

Comment: Part of the problem here is that `filter(lambda:...` is inherently hard to read (vs, say, a filtered comprehension). Presumably, you prefer your notation because it includes an `if`.

Comment: Fair enough. And that might explain why I didn't come up with `lambda (x, y): x not in b` in the first place (which is illegal in 3.0 anyway).

Comment: @Eric oh really,   "filter(labmda" is hard to read ? Probably it is only your opinion, this really depends on experience.  However here is only one disadvantage of using filter with lambdas - it's performance. generators and plain if works faster.

Comment: @Reishin: It's more than just my opinion - Guido himself wanted to remove them. See a related post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3013722/102441)