# If statement in lambdas Python

Tags: python

I wanted to declare an `if` statement inside a `lambda` function:

Suppose:

```
cells = ['Cat', 'Dog', 'Snake', 'Lion', ...]
result = filter(lambda element: if 'Cat' in element, cells)
```

Is it possible to filter out the 'cat' into `result`?

Comment: What's the intended value of result?

Comment: What does not work? Where is the problem? What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to filter out all the strings that have `'cat'` in them, then just use

```
>>> cells = ['Cat', 'Dog', 'Snake', 'Lion']
>>> filter(lambda x: not 'cat' in x.lower(), cells)
['Dog', 'Snake', 'Lion']
```

If you want to keep those that have `'cat'` in them, just remove the `not`.

```
>>> filter(lambda x: 'cat' in x.lower(), cells)
['Cat']
```

You could use a list comprehension here too.

```
>>> [elem for elem in cells if 'cat' in elem.lower()]
['Cat']
```

Comment: Note that `'cat' in x.lower()` will filter words like "catch"

Comment: Yes, I know, I was just giving an example of a use case. :)

Comment: Since you have the most votes, you might want to add the equivalent list comprehension, i.e. `output = [x for x in cells if x.lower()=='cat']`.

Answer (score 2):

The `element` means the elements of the iterable. You just need to compare.

```
>>> cells = ['Cat', 'Dog', 'Snake', 'Lion']
>>> filter(lambda element: 'Cat' == element, cells)
['Cat']
>>>
```

Or if you want to use `in` to test whether the element contains something, don't use `if`. A single `if` expression is syntax error.

```
>>> filter(lambda element: 'Cat' in element, cells)
['Cat']
>>>
```

Comment: Are you sure that this is the intented behaviour? 'cause it looks pretty nonsense if understood like that. Or at least purposeless. Filtering an element that you can check with simple `in` operator?

Comment: I am not sure. But according to OP's description, (s)he seems to want the behaviour like this.

Comment: Well, to me his description its not clear what he wants. There are way better solutions to do the task. Using `filter` for a single element seems kinda stupid.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `if`, here. Your `lambda` will return a boolean value and [`filter()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) will only return those elements for which the `lambda` returns `True`.

It looks like you are trying to do either:

```
>>> filter(lambda cell: 'Cat' in cell , cells)
['Cat']
```

Or...

```
>>> filter(lambda cell: 'Cat' not in cell, cells)
['Dog', 'Snake', 'Lion', '...']
```

...I cannot tell which.

Note that `filter(function, iterable)` is equivalent to `[item for item in iterable if function(item)]` and  it's more usual (Pythonic) to use the list comprehension for this pattern:

```
>>> [cell for cell in cells if 'Cat' in cell]
['Cat']
>>> [cell for cell in cells if 'Cat' not in cell]
['Dog', 'Snake', 'Lion', '...']
```

See [List filtering: list comprehension vs. lambda + filter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3013449/78845) for more information on that.