# How to use map() to call class methods on a list of objects

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to call `object.method()` on a list of objects.

I have tried this but can't get it to work properly

```
newList = map(method, objectList)
```

I get the error `method is not defined` but I know that is because it is a class method and not a local function.

Is there a way to do this with `map()`, or a similar built in function?  Or will I have to use a generator/list comprehension?

**edit** Could you also explain the advantages or contrast your solution to using this list comprehension?

```
newList = [object.method() for object in objectList]
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`newList = map(method, objectList)` would call `method(object)` on each `object` in `objectlist`.

The way to do this with map would require a lambda function, e.g.:

```py
map(lambda obj: obj.method(), objectlist)
```

A list comprehension might be *marginally* faster, seeing as you wouldn't need a lambda, which has some overhead (discussed a bit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013449/list-filtering-list-comprehension-vs-lambda-filter)).

Comment: A little addition: if you want to be able to use any old `method` and any old `objectList`: `new_lister = lambda method, objectList: map(lambda obj: obj.method(), objectList)`. Now you can do `newList = new_lister(foo_method, list_of_foos)` etc.

Comment: Can you explain the use of the lambda function?  I thought map passed the elements of the list as parameters to the function.  How does the lambda function accept the objects as parameters?

Comment: `lambda obj: obj.method()` is equivalent to: `def foo(obj): obj.method`. So `map` is indeed passing the elements of the list as parameters. Each element will be passed in as `obj`, the first argument of the lambda. Make sense?

Comment: @CharlesMarsh yep, this seems like the most direct answer to my question.  Although I did end up using the list comprehension, your is also one line.

Answer (score 23):

Use [`operator.methodcaller()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.methodcaller):

```
from operator import methodcaller

map(methodcaller('methodname'), object_list)
```

This works for any list of objects that all have the same method (by name); it doesn't matter if there are different types in the list.

Comment: Jeez, do you remember all of these useful built in functions off of the top of your head?

Answer (score 6):

If the contents of the list are all instances of the same class, you can prefix the method name with the class name.

```
class Fred:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
    def frob(self):
        return self.val

freds = [Fred(4), Fred(8), Fred(15)]
print map(Fred.frob, freds)
```

Result:

```
[4, 8, 15]
```

This can also be done if the elements of the list are subclasses of the specified class. However, it will still call the specified implementation of the method, even if that method is overridden in the subclass. Example:

```
class Fred:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
    def frob(self):
        return self.val

class Barney(Fred):
    def frob(self):
        return self.val * 2

freds = [Fred(4), Barney(8), Barney(15)]
#You might expect the barneys to return twice their val. ex. [4, 16, 30]
#but the actual output is [4, 8, 15]
print map(Fred.frob, freds)
```

Comment: This will fail if there are objects in the list that are not at the very least subclasses.

Comment: does this have something to do with `map()` using the `self` argument since map passes the second argument as a parameter to the function defined in the first argument?  I've never found a case where I had to understand that argument.

Comment: Map doesn't do anything special in that regard. It's just a side effect of the fact that `Fred.frob(x)` behaves identically to `x.frob()`, assuming x is an instance of `Fred`.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone was wondering, I did a small performance test (for my specific use case, so take it with a grain of salt):

```py
import timeit
import numpy as np
from typing import Dict, NamedTuple

ROWS = 42
COLS = 12

class Item(NamedTuple):
    """An item"""

    row_min: int
    column_min: int
    row_max: int
    column_max: int

    def info(self) -> Dict[str, int]:
        """
        Converts item to dictionary
        """
        return {
            "row_min": self.row_min * ROWS,
            "column_min": self.row_max * ROWS,
            "row_max": self.column_min * COLUMNS,
            "column_max": self.column_max * COLUMNS,
        }

items = create_items()

def time_func(func):
    timings = timeit.repeat(func, number=10000, repeat=10)
    return np.mean(timings), np.std(timings)


tests = {
    "map w/lambda": lambda: map(lambda itm: itm.info(), items),
    "map w/static": lambda: map(Item.info, items),
    "map w/method caller": lambda: map(methodcaller('info'), items),
    "list comprehension": lambda: [itm.info() for itm in items],
}

for name, func in tests.items():
    mean, std = time_func(func)
    print(f"{name:25}: {mean:.5} +/- {std:.5}")
```

And I am getting these results:

```
map w/lambda             : 0.0026292 +/- 0.00063354
map w/static             : 0.0016314 +/- 8.6045e-05
map w/method caller      : 0.0021618 +/- 0.00019693
list comprehension       : 1.934 +/- 0.016754
```