# How to use map() to call method common to list of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

**TL;DR:** Basically, I'm trying to use `Array.prototype.map()` to call a method common to a list of context objects.

Say I have some code like this:

```
a.doSomething();
b.doSomething();
c.doSomething();
d.doSomething();
e.doSomething();
...
```

This is overly verbose. I want to be able to shorten this code up to something like this

```
[a, b, c, d, e].map(doSomething);
```

because I don't want to have to use a `for` loop.

How would I be able to do this with the native `map` function in JS, **without** any external libraries?

Thank you in advance! If this post is too long, I will happily edit it. Just scream at me.

**Related questions:**

[How to use map() to call class methods on a list of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17997959/how-to-use-map-to-call-class-methods-on-a-list-of-objects)

[How to call same method for a list of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682012/how-to-call-same-method-for-a-list-of-objects)

*I didn't use the info in the related questions because Python and JS use different paradigms and I don't have assurance they'll work the same. If I'm wrong here, please don't hesitate to burn me at the stake.*

**Extra info, disregard if you'd like:**

I've [already](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) [RTFM](http://bit.ly/1I1RjZo), and the wording and examples suggest I can't do the above with `map`. The MDN docs describe `map` as "calling a provided function ***on*** every element in an array", while the MSDN docs say it "calls a function ***on*** each element of an array, and returns an array." I'm not trying to call a method *on* an array, I'm trying to call a method *from* several context objects. If this is not possible, is there a native polyfill?

I'm using this in a game, so speed is my main concern. If there is a more optimal way to code this, please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replied without thinking. `Array#map` is supported in most browsers today and was apart of ES5. See the MDN link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

```
[1,2,3,4,5].map(function(item){ console.log(item)}
```

will print:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

and return undefined. If you return something like:

```
[1,2,3,4,5].map(function(item){return 2*item})
```

it will return:

```
[2,4,6,8,10]
```

But it's not neccessary to return anything. You can just as easily do a forEach.

```
items.forEach(function(item){items.method()}
```

It's all O(n) time, because to apply anything to n items in the array, it takes at least n time. For loop is as good as it gets.

**WRONG**

<strike>ES6 supports `#map` but it's not available on all browsers/Node.js without different settings being set.</strike>

Underscorejs has this functionality, if you do want an external library. See their map documentation: http://underscorejs.org/#map

I use it in server code, no problem. Should probably work for your game. If page load time is an issue, you can always extend the prototype of `Array` yourself.

Comment: "See the MDN link:" I linked your very link in my question. But thank you very much! You've succinctly answered all my questions! You're a lifesaver.

Comment: MDN and MSDN are my go-to references.

Comment: It's just habit for me (when I'm not rushing) to post my source and then explain. Most of these posts aren't just to help you, the OP, but to help the next person who comes along with the same question.

Answer (score 2):

The closest I can think of is

```
[a, b, c, d, e].forEach(function(item) {item.doSomething()});
```

using [].map would be pointless for your purpose

edit, you could also do something like this

```
Array.prototype.fnName = function(methodName) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    this.forEach(function(item) { 
        item[methodName].apply(item, args); 
    });
};
```

I've used `fnName`, you could call it `fnMap` or something else that makes sense to you

you'd use it like

```
[a,b,c].fnName('doSomething', param1, param2 ...)
```

Comment: I was wondering if this might work the same way as `map`. Much appreciated, sir, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`Array.map()` calls given function for every item in array. That’s where anonymous functions can be very appropriate:

```
[a, b, c].map(function (item) { item.doSomething(); });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, sir! I was tossing this same idea around in my head for a while, but I couldn't see it working like I expected. How would you call `doSomething()` with arguments, though? Would I use the built-in `arguments` array?

Comment: I see you showed me just that, and I'm sure multiple args would work similarly. Feel free to put me in the dunking pool now!

Answer (score 0):

Seeing this post is pretty old, I wanted to give some elements that might complement the other answers.

Let's take a simple class `A` which has a method `double`.

```js
class A {
  constructor(n) { this.n = n; }
  double() { return 2 * this.n; }
}
```

We will have an array of instances to work on.

```js
const data = [ new A(3), new A(12), new A(4), new A(10) ];
```

---

#### Function wrapper

The [`Array#map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method takes in a function callback that it will execute on each of the elements of that array.

Essentially it comes down to *wrapping the method call on the object*. To do so we can use a standard function like:

```
data.map(function(o) { return o.double() });
```

Usually however you would come across an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) instead:

```
data.map(o => o.double());
```

which alleviates the need for parentheses, curly braces and the `return` statement.

---

#### Destructuring

Now we could try to improve this. We can actually [destructure objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) in the function's header. Below, we are retrieving double directly from the object and calling it:

```
data.map(({ double }) => double());
```

However, that won't work...

> TypeError: `this` is `undefined`

What happens is, we are not calling `double` on the current object. This is because of function binding, when independently calling `double` as a function we are leaving the value of `this` unset.

We could bind the function to the object,

```
data.map((o, _, __, fn=o.double) => fn.bind(o)())
```

but... this would defeat the purpose of going after a shorter version.

---

#### Class member arrow functions!

However, there **is** a way around this by using class member arrow functions.

```
class A {
  constructor(n) { this.n = n; }
  double = () => { return 2 * this.n; }
}
```

This way we bypass the need for a bind when calling the method.

Then we can successfully do:

```
data.map(({ double } => double());
```

Keep in mind, this is not supported by all browsers. And since you will have to fiddle with your class declarations in order to use this syntax sugar. I wouldn't really recommend it. Class member arrow functions are quite nice for event handlers though...

---

#### Demo:

```js
class A {
  constructor(n) { this.n = n; }
  double() { return 2 * this.n; }
  triple = () => { return 3 * this.n; }
}

const data = [new A(3), new A(12), new A(4), new A(10)];

console.log(data.map(o => o.double()));

// console.log(data.map(({ double }) => double())); // won't work!

console.log(data.map((o, _,__, fn=o.double) => fn.bind(o)())); // ugly

console.log(data.map(({triple}) => triple()));
```