# Confusion about efficiencies after evaluating list comprehension performance

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I experimented a little bit with list comprehensions and the `filter()` function today, because I was interested to see if there are significant efficiency improvements if using one over the other.
The results are a little bit confusing. When I filtered for even numbers, list comprehensions outperformed the traditional nested structure and the `filter()` function by ~1.5x (i.e., it was ~1.5x faster).
But when I was using a function to check if a number was a prime number or not, the `filter()` function was suddenly the fastest.

I posted more details below, and I uploaded the code at github if you want to try it out yourself: https://github.com/rasbt/list_comprehension_test

I tested the code with different range maximum values `n` multiple times to make sure that the results are consistent and not affected by some temporary background process on my machine.

My questions:

- Any idea why filter function is so slow when filtering for even numbers? Could it be, because of the lambda function or because I am converting the generator object into a list?
- why are the results for the is_prime function so similar, and why is the filter function the fastest here?

---

### 1st Part: collecting even numbers

---

a) loop and else-if

```
even_nums = []
for i in range(1, n):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        even_nums.append(i)
```

b) list comprehension:

```
even = [i for i in range(1, n) if i % 2 == 0]
```

c) filter() function

```
even_nums = list(filter((lambda x: x%2 != 0), range(1, n)))
```

**results for is_even**

- loop and else-if: 1x (reference)
- list comprehension: 1.5x faster
- filter() function: 0.9x faster

---

### 2nd Part: Collecting Prime Numbers

---

```
def is_prime(num):
    """ Returns True if input integer is a prime number. """
    prime = True
    if num < 2:
        prime = False

    elif num == 2:
        prime = True
    else:
        for i in range(2, num):
            if num % i == 0:
                prime = False    
                break
    return prime
```

a) loop and else-if

```
primes = []
for i in range(1, n):
    if is_prime(i):
        primes.append(i)
```

b) list comprehension:

```
primes = [i for i in range(1, n) if is_prime(i)]
```

c) filter() function

```
primes = list(filter(is_prime, range(1, n)))
```

**results for is_prime**

- loop and else-if: 1x (reference)
- list comprehension: 0.98x faster
- filter() function: 1.13x faster

Comment: I guess it depends what dominates, checking the value or appending to the existing list. In Python 2 you could see if [`itertools.ifilter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilter) makes any difference.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good point

Comment: possible duplicate of [List filtering: list comprehension vs. lambda + filter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013449/list-filtering-list-comprehension-vs-lambda-filter)

Comment: Have you tried doing performance analysis?

Docs for profiling are [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html) and there is an existing SO question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-can-you-profile-a-python-script)

Comment: Haven't heard of it, yet. But looks very very useful to me, I will use it to do a more comprehensive analysis/check in the next couple of days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you implement the first test this way, the results should be consistent with the second test:

```
is_even = lambda i: i % 2 == 0
even = [i for i in range(1, n) if is_even(i)]
```

In the `filter` implementation, there is a function call once per iteration (the lambda), which is an extra step. This difference is not present in the second test because in that case both implementations already consist of a call (`is_prime`) once per iteration.

As for why `filter` is slightly faster, I suspect it's related to `filter` being native rather than python code. Consider that the list comprehension still has an additional evaluation of python code per iteration: namely, the `i` before the `for`. This evaluation step would not be necessary in `filter` which could directly yield the value in the native implementation.