# Given a list of words, remove those with more than four characters. How should I do that?

Tags: python

```
def remove_long_words(words):
    """Given a list of words, remove any that are longer
    than four letters and return a new, shorter list.

    w = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'eighteen']

    remove_long_words(w)
    ['one', 'two', 'four']

    w = ['eighteen']

    remove_long_words(w)
    []

    w = ['one', 'two', 'four', 'six']

    remove_long_words(w)
    ['one', 'two', 'four', 'six']

    remove_long_words(['one']) == ['one']
    True
    """

replace this line with your code
```

Comment: Fix your code formatting, and read up on list comprehensions.

Comment: This sounds like a homework question.

Comment: Have you tried to write any code yourself? You should try that first and come back with specific questions about the problems you're having.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: Hint: you are thinking about it backwards. Don't _remove_ words with more than four characters; _keep_ words with four or fewer.

Comment: `return filter(lambda x: len(x) <= 4, words)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [List filtering: list comprehension vs. lambda + filter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013449/list-filtering-list-comprehension-vs-lambda-filter)

Answer (score 2):

What I have below uses the idea of ***'List Comprehensions'***. you can read more about it, here: http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

I suggest you to look over the code and read about list comprehension and try to understand what is going on.

```
def remove_long_words(words):
    """(list) -> list

    Return a list of words that are less than or equal to
    the length 4.

    >>> remove_long_words(['eighteen'])
    []
    >>> remove_long_words(['one', 'two', 'four', 'six'])
    ['one', 'two', 'four', 'six']
    >>> remove_long_words(['one']) == ['one']
    True
    >>> remove_long_words(['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'eighteen'])
    ['one', 'two', 'four']

    """
    return [i for i in words if len(i) <= 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new_list = [x for x in old_list if len(x) < 4]
```

List comprehensions ftw.

There's also the [`filter`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#filter) function

Comment: doesn't pass OP's spec