# Most efficient way to find objetcs in list of objects

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have a list or array (what is the correct term in python?) of objects.
What is the most efficient way to get all objects matching a condition?

I could iterate over the list and check each element, but that doesn't seem very efficient.

```
objects = []
for object in list:
  if object.value == "123":
    objects.add(object)
```

Comment: "Efficient" is a vague term. Do you mean "the fastest way" or "the simplest way"?

Comment: i mean the fastest way

Comment: Provide more details then (see below).

Answer (score 6):

This is the simplest way:

```
objects = [x for x in someList if x.value == 123]
```

If you're looking for a *faster* solution, you have to tell us more about your objects and how the source list is built. For example, if the property in question is unique among the objects, you can have better performance using `dict` instead of `list`. Another option is to keep the list sorted and use `bisect` instead of the linear search. Do note however, that these optimization efforts start making sense when the list grows really big, if you have less than ~500 elements, just use a comprehension and stop worrying.

Comment: Pythonic, Python 2 / Python 3 compatible, efficient, no lambdas. +1

Comment: This is simpler, more Pythonic, and faster than `filter()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `filter`

```
objects = filter(lambda i: i.value == '123', l)
```

*Note to self*
Apparently the ["filter vs list comp"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013449/list-filtering-list-comprehension-vs-lambda-filter) debate starts flame wars.

Comment: How is this "the most efficient way"?

Comment: It is one-line, Pythonic, and `O(N)`, if you know a more efficient way feel free to post your own answer ;)

Comment: The most efficient way possible with Python would be a native extension module searching in the list, but that's not a serious option for like 99.9999999 % of possible use cases. For these 99.99 % filter is the absolutely right thing to do. +1

Comment: It's 2 times slower than a list comprehension from @georg's answer.