# Using regex to grep a string in Python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to grep two kinds of patterns in a list using re in python:

```
'<xyz>number followed by optional *</xyz>'
'name="namepad">number</xyz>
```

Using regex in python, I am not able to get the data with asterisk. Here is a sample session, what can I do so that the filter also returns the first element?

```
>>> k = ['<xyz>27*</xyz>', 'name="namePad">22</xyz>']
>>> f = filter(lambda x:re.search('^name="namePad"|^<xyz>[0-9]{1,3}\*"  <\/xyz>',x), k)
>>> f
['name="namePad">22</xyz>']
```

Comment: what is your expected Output?

Comment: All of k (first line):
['<xyz>27*</xyz>', 'name="namePad">22</xyz>']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex has mismatched `"` quotes. Try this:

```
filter(lambda x:re.search(r'^name="namePad"|^<xyz>[\d]{1,3}\*?</xyz>',x), k)
```

It will give you the following:

> ['27*', 'name="namePad">22']

Comment: What is the ? after \* for?

Comment: It will still match the numbers, in case `*` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`re.match`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) since to  check for a match only at the beginning of the string. Also you don't need [*filter*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013449/list-filtering-list-comprehension-vs-lambda-filter) use [*list comprehensions*](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) instead.

```
>>> [i for i in k if re.match(r'(<xyz>|name="namePad">)\d+\*?', i)]
['<xyz>27*</xyz>', 'name="namePad">22</xyz>']
```

The `?` after `*` mean that `*` is optional you can read more about quantifiers [Here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html)