# handling exception KeyError - Python

Tags: python, keyerror

I am getting a "`KeyError`" for a non-existing `key` in following code:

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM table1 where col1 = 'test'")
res = c.fetchall()
sum = 0
for x in res:
    print "res: ",res

    d = {"num1"     : [  str(testVal[x[2]]['num1']) for x in res ],
         "num2"     : [ str(testVal[x[2]]['num2']) for x in res ],
         }
    conn.close()
```

This is the error:

```
    "num1": [  str(testVal[x[2]]['num1']) for x in res ],
KeyError: u'13'
```

How can I check to see if that key has value then assign it to `"num1", "num2"`.

Comment: Could you edit your code? the quotes are pretty messy.. Also, it would be helpful to know on which line the error occurs.

Comment: Also, `dict.get('key', defaultValue)` is quite useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that:

`"num1": [  str(ch_id[x[2]]['num1']) for x in res if x[2] in ch_id]`

Since the execution is greedy, Python will not evaluate `str(ch_id[x[2]]['num1'])` if the condition is `False`, so you get no errors. It will just skip the missing keys. If you don't know this syntax, you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013449/list-filtering-list-comprehension-vs-lambda-filter).