# How to delete multiple items from a list based on a condition in python

Tags: python, list

I have a list like this in python.

```
list1=[1,2,4,0,5,0,3,0]
```

I want to delete all 0's from the list. How can i do it

Comment: This question shows 2 methods and has a lot of information on the differences between them: [List filtering: list comprehension vs. lambda + filter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013449/list-filtering-list-comprehension-vs-lambda-filter)

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = [item for item in list1 if item != 0]
```

Comment: `[item for item in list1 if item is not 0]` is even more explicit

Comment: @Brobin but also technically wrong, you shouldn't assume that the python interpreter has a cache of [common] integers.

Comment: @TomDalton: it'll work in the case of zero and some small integers due to peephole optimizations

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: But you can't guarantee that it will be like this for every implementation of Python and for future versions.