# How to remove all elements that doesn't meet requirements from list

Tags: python, list

I have a list:

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a']
```

I use following code to remove elements that doesn't meet requirements:

```
[my_list.remove(element) for element in my_list if 'a' not in element]
```

but instead of expected `['a', 'a', 'a']` got `['a', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'a']`. Seems that after removing `'b'` Python doesn't check following `'c'` elements...

Please advise me how to resolve this issue and efficiently remove all unnecessary elements from list.

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3013449/390819)

Comment: Do you want in-place modification to the list or a new list with designated elements absent?

Comment: Yes. I want to modify existed list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to modify (shrink) the existing list in-place, here's something that does so:

```
def remove_all_on_predicate(predicate, list_):
    deserving_removal = [elem for elem in list_ if predicate(elem)]
    for elem in deserving_removal:
        list_.remove(elem)
    return None

>>> remove_all_on_predicate(lambda x: "a" not in x, my_list)
>>> my_list
['a', 'a', 'a']
```

Answer (score 8):

Other answers solve the problem, but let me explain what's going on here.

```
>>> lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a']
>>> for each in lst:
...     if 'a' not in each:
...         lst.remove(each)
>>> lst
['a', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'a']
```

#### Iteration 1:

```
#   V                                     - Current position of loop
# ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a']

if 'a' not in each: #Output False
```

#### Iteration 2:

```
#        V                                - Current position of loop
# ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a']

if 'a' not in each: #Output True
    list.remove(each)  #Element from position 1 ('b') in list is removed
```

#### Iteration 3:

```
#             V                         |___ Supposed to be like this  
# ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a']   |

#             V                         |___ Updated list
# ['a', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a']        |

if 'a' not in each: #Output False
```

That's why your 'c' is skipped in output list.

Now to solve your problem, instead of deleting all non-`a`, it's a better approach to create a list with only `a`. ([Trengot's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32369849/2251411))

### Edit:

since your `my_list` is a collection of character, it is better to use `if 'a' != element`, because `'a' not in element` will scan through each letter of element, and it will also remove all elements having letter `'a'` ([Check this to understand how `in` works in Python](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#index-6)).

For example if your `my_list = ['a','abc','fd','b','c']`, `'a' not in 'abc'` will return `False`, and element `'abc'` won't be removed.

Answer (score 3):

Filter the list into a new one selecting the elements you do want rather than removing the ones you don't. Then either use the new one or assign it to the old.

```
my_list = [element for element in my_list if 'a' in element]
```

As Peter Wood pointed out, this will assign a new object to `my_list`. If you want to keep the same list object (eg if it's referenced elsewhere as well) assign the new list to `my_list[:]`.

```
my_list[:] = [element for element in my_list if 'a' in element]
```

Comment: If you want to keep the original list object, assign to `my_list[:]`

Answer (score 1):

As you have discovered, attempting to remove elements from a list that you are iterating over may not do what you expect. Ashwani Agarwal's answer illustrates why it fails, and the other answers show various techniques that can be used to perform the removals correctly. Another technique that can be useful when you have a very large list that you can't afford to copy is to iterate over it in reverse:

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a']
for element in reversed(my_list):
    if 'a' not in element:
        my_list.remove(element)
        print(element, my_list)

print('Final:', my_list)

my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a']
for element in reversed(my_list):
    if 'a' in element:
        my_list.remove(element)
        print(my_list)

print('Final:', my_list)
```

**output**

```
c ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a']                                                                                                               
c ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a']                                                                                                                    
b ['a', 'a', 'b', 'a']                                                                                                                         
b ['a', 'a', 'a']                                                                                                                              
Final: ['a', 'a', 'a']                                                                                                                         
['b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a']                                                                                                                 
['b', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'a']
['b', 'c', 'b', 'c']
Final: ['b', 'c', 'b', 'c']
```

This code uses the `reversed()` function, which returns an iterator over the iterable you pass to it; it doesn't copy the iterable.

I should mention that this technique is less efficient than the filtering approaches given in other answers. That's because each call of `my_list.remove(element)` has to scan through `my_list` until it finds a matching element, so it has complexity O(n**2) where `n` is the number of elements in the list;  the filtering algorithms have a complexity of O(n). So as I said earlier, this approach is only useful when the list is so large that you can't afford the RAM to create a new list.

Another thing I need to mention about the code in your question: you are using a list comprehension to loop over a list when you should be using plain `for` loop. `list.remove()` returns `None`, so your code is needlessly creating a list full of `None`s and then throwing that list away. The general rule is: don't use a list comprehension purely for the side effects of a function you call in it.

Comment: Just awesome :)  it would be even nice if you show a iteration flow like agarwal did

Comment: @VigneshKalai: Thanks! But I think my `print()` calls in the loops show the flow adequately. :)

Comment: It was just that I got confused at the beginning how your method works and seeing your print I found that `remove` removes the first occurrence of the element I just thought it would be easy to understand for a new python programmer.Last but not least `beautiful answer  `

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [filter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter)

```
my_list = filter(lambda x: 'a' in x, my_list)
```