# Filter Python list

Tags: python, list

I have an list in Python that looks like this:

```
myarray = [('31.10', 'John', 'Smith', 'ZK'),('01.11', 'John', 'Smith', 'OK'),('31.10', 'John', 'Doe', 'ZK'),('01.11', 'John', 'Doe', 'ZK')]
```

I would like to filter by 2 keys. The 2 Name keys.

ex. filter myarray contains John and Doe to get:

```
01.11 John Doe ZK
31.10 John Doe ZK
```

Comment: You have a list containing tuples. Have you tried anything yourself yet?

Comment: i tried many different combinations with result = filter(lambda x: x[0] is "Doe", myarray) but i can't even filter it by only one key.

The output was only []

Comment: So what was the output you *did* get in that case? Please do add that to your question, it helps frame the context and lets us know how much you already know. You can [edit] it.

Comment: can you modify your original datastructure to atleast contain a named tuple  (contained in collections...so import collections) instead of a tuple?...in this way its more readable to write a code such as filter( lambda x: x.firstname=="John" and x.lastname=="Doe", myarray)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to test each tuple in the list:

```
for entry in myarray:
    if entry[1:3] == ('John', 'Doe'):
        print ' '.join(entry)
```

I used slicing to select just the parts at index `1` and `2` there, but you could also use tuple unpacking:

```
for num1, first, last, token in myarray:
    if (first, last) == ('John', 'Doe'):
        print num1, first, last, token
```

or if the tuple equality there is not as clear to you what it does, use separate comparisons and `and`:

```
for num1, first, last, token in myarray:
    if first == 'John' and last == 'Doe':
        print num1, first, last, token
```

Answer (score 1):

There is good discussion of the principles here: 
[List filtering: list comprehension vs. lambda + filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013449/list-filtering-list-comprehension-vs-lambda-filter)

Slightly adapting it to your problem:

```
def filterbyvalue(seq, position, value):
   for el in seq:
       if el[position]==value: yield el

myarray = [('31.10', 'John', 'Smith', 'ZK'),('01.11', 'John', 'Smith', 'OK'),('31.10', 'John', 'Doe', 'ZK'),('01.11', 'John', 'Doe', 'ZK')]

results = filterbyvalue(myarray, 2, "Doe")
for x in results:
    print(x)
```

The filterbyvalue function returns a generator, which can be called as normal.