# Python 2to3, iterating over list conditionally (filter vs list-comprehension)

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension, python-2to3

I am in the process of porting a bunch of scripts from Py2 -> Py3 using the `2to3` tool. One particular suggested change confused me a bit, so I'd appreciate some help with that:

The original line is:

```
for r in filter(lambda r: r.dir == direction, hm_regions):
    ... # do stuff with r
```

`hm_regions` holds `namedtuples` which have a property called `dir` and using this loop I iterate over those that match a given direction parameter.

The suggested change is

```
for r in [r for r in hm_regions if r.dir == direction]:
```

I understand that this does essentially the same thing, so in theory the results should not change at all (haven't tried). But I find the double `for` loop very ugly, and I guess this is not the prettiest, most graceful way to do this iteration.

I have also tried `for r in hm_regions if r.dir == direction:` which fails due to syntax error, which was a bit of a frustration.

**EDIT:** Another question here is if it makes sense to change at all? I realize that the underlying motivation for the the suggested change is that `filter` doesn't return a list anymore. But in this context I do not use the list, in any more than iterating over it. Thus it should work just as well, right?

Comment: Filtering is slower, for what it's worth. See [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013449/list-filtering-list-comprehension-vs-lambda-filter)

Answer (score 0):

> But I find the double for loop very ugly, and I guess this is not the prettiest, most graceful way to do this iteration.
>   Suggestions?

Use simple `if`:

```
for r in hm_regions:
    if r.dir == direction:
        # do stuff
```

or

```
for r in hm_regions:
    if r.dir != direction:
        continue
    # do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree that two for loops in one line isn't the most pleasing thing to look at, but I wouldn't overthink the solution too much. Some options:

1) If you're deadset on keeping the list comprehension, break it into two lines:

```
lst = [r for r in hm_regions if r.dir == direction]
for item in lst:
    ...
```

2) Use an if within the loop, if you don't mind ditching the comprehension:

```
for r in hm_regions:
    if r.dir == direction:
        ...
```

Edit: You might want to check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013449/list-filtering-list-comprehension-vs-lambda-filter). A generator may be a good alternative, but it depends on the context of your code.