# Why does the filter function exist?

Tags: python

If [list comprehension is better than `filter`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3013686/3120489), as it performs slighly better and is considered more readable (arguably, in my opinion), why does `filter` even exist?

I use it all the time, but if the consensus is that list comprehensions are better, what are the reasons why we have the `filter` function?

Comment: It almost didn't exist. http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196

Comment: From Guido himself: [here](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196)

Comment: While not an answer, I think it's interesting to note the emphasis on 'beauty' in python; in several places, list comprehension is posed as an alternative for those who don't view filter as 'beautiful' --  or vice versa.
http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013449/list-filtering-list-comprehension-vs-lambda-filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Way, way back in the day, way before we had list comprehensions, some guy who liked functional programming wrote up `map` and `filter` and submitted the change, and it got put in. That's about it.