# Check all active users from array

Tags: python, django, logic

I need to choose all active users with the easiest way

```
users = [{'id': 1, 'active': False}, {'id': 2, 'active': True}, {'id': 3, 'active': True}, {'id': 4, 'active': True}, {'id': 5, 'active': True}, {'id': 6, 'active': True}]
```

Comment: What exactly are you attempting to do? You want to return a list which only contains the dictionaries where `active` equals `True`?

Comment: Why not use ORM and filter active users in your query? How you get the `users` list?

Comment: simple: u = [user for user in users if user['active']]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a list comprehension would work fine:

```
users = [user for user in users if user['active']]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do that with list comprehension,

```
active_users = [user for user in users if user['active']]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter). It will return a list in py2.x and a generator for py3.x

```
filter(lambda x:x['active'], users)
```

Comment: For anybody looking for a discussion of "should I use a list comprehension or filter": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013449/list-filtering-list-comprehension-vs-lambda-filter

Comment: `x['active']` not `x['xctive']`

Answer (score 0):

```
active_user = [user['id']  for user in users if user['active']]
```