# Create a new list of strings that only contains the names shared by 1,000 people or more

Tags: python-3.x

```
#numerical_list is the list.

for each in numerical_list:
    x=each[0]
    x1=each[1]

    if x1 >= 1000:

        thousand_or_greater.append(x)

print (thousand_or_greater)
```

Can someone explain the **for** loop shown here ? *Is there another alternate solution* ?

Thank you.

Comment: at first, post our actual `numerical_list`

Comment: What part(s) of this don't you understand?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List filtering: list comprehension vs. lambda + filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013449/list-filtering-list-comprehension-vs-lambda-filter)

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest  the original list (numerical_list) was basically [['Casey', 176544.328149],
 ['Riley', 154860.66517300002],
etc.  and was just names followed by how many people had that name.

Answer (score 0):

You are looping over a list of some form of data structure with at least 2 indexes and if the 2nd index is greater than or equal to 1000, you are assigning the value of the first index to the list

```
thousand_or_greater = []
numerical_list = [['Casey', 176544.328149], ['Riley', 154860.66517300002]]

for each in numerical_list:
    x=each[0]
    x1=each[1]
    if x1 >= 1000:
        thousand_or_greater.append(x)

print (thousand_or_greater)
>> ['Casey', 'Riley']
```

This can be shortened using the following list comprehension:

```
[x[0] for x in numerical_list if x[1] >= 1000]
>> ['Casey', 'Riley']
```

Comment: [['Casey', 176544.328149],
 ['Riley', 154860.66517300002],
etc. was the original numerical_list. It basically displayed names followed by how many people had that name. The question was to print or display only those names which were used by 1000 or more people. Thank you for the explaination.

Comment: It should still work if the data structure is a list of lists and your original solution works for the problem