# List comprehension without 'for'

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Often when working with lists in Python, I end up wanting to simply filter out items from a list.

```
numbers = [5, 1, 4, 2, 7, 4]
big_nums = [num for num in numbers if num > 2]
```

To me this seems unnecessarily verbose.  I have to define and use num in two separate statements (`num for num ...`), even though I don't do any operation on `num`.

I tried `[num in numbers if num > 2]`, but python throws a `SyntaxError` with this.

Is there a more concise way of doing this in Python?

#### Edit:

My question is if there is a better way to do what I'm trying to do in Python.  There are many times where there's been a construct in Python I didn't know about, but which made my code better and more readable.

I am not asking about performance tradeoffs between `filter` and list comprehension.  I have no problem with list comprehension, but I also had no problem with building lists with standard `for` loops before I learned about list comprehension.

Comment: This seems like a code golf question, not a practical one, Python code is meant to be readable

Comment: `[num in numbers if num > 2]` makes it seem like you were trying to use a ternary expression (`x if y else z`) that contained an `in` expression and you just forgot the else-clause

Comment: I don't see a single thing wrong with that list comprehension.

Comment: Note: the dupe will answer your question and much more. A simple "list comprehension alternative" google search would've turned that up as the first result.

Comment: FWIW, if `numbers` were a 1D Numpy array you could do `numbers[numbers>2]`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ The [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3013449) is informative, but it does not answer my question.  I'm guessing the answer to my question is 'no', but my question is not the same as the suggested dupe (see my edit)

Comment: "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.
Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch." ;)

Comment: @PM2Ring Good point, so this question is for those of us who aren't Dutch and need a little help

Comment: Fair enough. :) The "one obvious way" principal isn't as strict as it used to be (eg we now have several ways to format strings), but generally, if there's an obvious way it's probably better to use it than to search for obscure alternatives, since the obvious way is probably easier to understand & more readable. OTOH, "practicality beats purity"...

Answer (score 9):

Well, you could use `filter`, it's slower and not as readable but you don't need the `for`:

```
list(filter(lambda x: x > 2, numbers))
```

or:

```
list(filter((2).__lt__, numbers))
```

However using magic methods like this is fragile, this will only work if the list only contains integers. As Chris_Rands pointed out you normally use `operator.lt` instead:

```
from functools import partial
from operator import lt
list(filter(partial(lt, 2), numbers))
```

That would also work if the list contains other numeric types except `int`.

Comment: Nice use of `__lt__`! +1

Comment: and probably faster too because no lambda

Comment: probably importing `lt` from operator would be more 'pythonic'?

Comment: What Jean-François said. Also, you could use splat unpacking instead of calling the `list` constructor: `[*filter((2).__lt__, numbers)]`. But I agree that the standard list comp way is better, even if the repetition is slightly annoying.

Comment: @Chris_Rands Maybe, since directly calling dunder methods is generally frowned upon; OTOH, there are occasions where it makes sense to call a dunder method directly, and IMHO this is one of them. But of course, it's even more Pythonic to just use the standard list comp syntax that the OP is complaining about. ;)