# Implement remove method in for list

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm trying to understand what the following function does, and in specific what does the `if` part is doing:

```
def remove(items, value):
    new_items = []
    found = False

    for item in items:
        if not found and item == value:  
            found = True
            continue
        new_items.append(item)
    if not found :
        raise ValueError('list.remove(x): x not in list')

    return new_items
```

The statement `if not found and item == value:` and the trick of variable `found` . can someone specifically explain it?

---

Thanks, Now I understand the example code snippet above. And I can write code to implement my idea

> My idea is to first make sure the value is in the initial list . then compare every item with that value, add the item which doesn't satisfy condition item != value to a new list new_items, finally return the new list.

```
def remove(items, value):
    new_items = []
    for item in items:
        if item == value :
            continue
        else : 
            new_items.append(item)
        if len(items) == len(new_items):
            print("This value is not in the list")
    return new_items
```

Comment: if you want to remove the value why do you want to add it to the initial list? your question is not clear

Comment: Can you clarify the problem? Is it a lack of understanding? Incorrect behavior? You're saying what you want to do, and doing it correctly AFAICT, so what is the problem? Is this not your code, and you're trying to figure it out?

Comment: @alfasin I add the item which should not be deleted to a new list and return that new list. then it appear that I delete an item from the beginning list

Comment: @alfasin this code seems to work (as described)... I think the question is "explain this line of 'my' code".

Comment: @ComplicatedPhenomenon if you have an item in the list and you call `remove` with that item - this code will remove it. I'm not sure I understand what you're asking...

Comment: Further, this code will remove *only* the first item that is equal to the item that was sent to the function: if there are other copies of this item in the list - those copies will not be removed. Is that what confuses you?

Comment: @I am trying to understand the specific implementation of that `remove` method

Comment: @alfasin you are right, it's not a perfect example still.

Comment: Have you tried creating sample data and writing down the algorithm on paper?

Comment: *then it appear that I delete an item from the beginning list*... That's not what this function does. The initial list is never modified

Comment: It sounds like ShadowRanger guessed correctly: you didn't write this code, and you want us to explain it to you, in particular, what that `if` block is doing. Is that correct?

Comment: BTW, you do know that `list` objects already have a `.remove` method, right?

Comment: @ShadowRanger It's not my code, I want to figure out this  code snippet

Comment: @PM2Ring Yes, I know. It 's nothing about re-inventing the wheels, I am learning about how to use very simple algorithm to implement these basic operations

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes,  you're right. The initial list is not modified, I construct  a new list.

Comment: Sure. Keep in mind `if len(items) == len(new_items)`... Should probably be `if value not in items`... Also, Your function can be simply written as `new_items = [x for x in items if x!=value]` or using the `filter()` function. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013449/list-filtering-list-comprehension-vs-lambda-filter

Comment: @cricket_007 Got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`found` is just a flag; while it's `False` (`not found` is `True`), you're checking each `item` against the target `value`. When you find a match, you set `found` to `True`, and bypass the item that matched (`continue` skips the rest of the body of the loop, returning to the top of the loop immediately, so `append` isn't called).

After that, `not found` is always `False`, and since `and` is a short-circuiting test, if the left hand side is `False`, then the right hand side isn't even checked. From there on, you just append all remaining items as you go. By using the flag and checking it first, you:

1. Avoid removing more than one copy of `value` from the newly created `list`
2. Avoid the work of comparing items once you've found a match (testing `not somebool` is the cheapest test available in Python beyond testing a compile time constant), speeding up the code a bit

Answer (score 1):

Since `found` is initialized to be `False` it means that `not found` is evaluated to `True`, so while we're iterating the items and until we've found the item we're looking for, we'll compare each `item == value` and if it evaluates to `True` we'll enter the `if` body and execute two things:

1. modify the value of `found` to `True`: which means that from now on
   we'll never enter that `if` block again
2. `continue` we'll "jump" over the part that adds this item that we
   found

To sum it up: when we'll run into the first occurrence of `value` during iteration, we'll flip the value of the flag `found` and we'll skip the part that adds it to the new list. This will result in adding all the items *but* this one to the new-list.