# select a sublist from a list of lists in python

Tags: python, list, sublist

I've got a list of lists `A`:

```
A = [ [0, 42, 2.6],
      [1, 20, 5.6],
      [2, 67, 3.5],
      [3, 12, 3.2],
      [4, 34, 1.1],
      [5, 74, 4.7],
      [6, 29, 2.9] ]
```

from which I'd like to extract a sub-list `B` containing only those lists whose second columns are lower than 30 (i.e., `B = [[1, 20, 5.6],[3, 12, 3.2],[6, 29, 2.9]]`)

Of course I may convert it to a `numpy` and use a `np.where`. However I was wondering whether there is a way of doing that just by using lists. I tried with a list comprehension, but I'm not very expert on that:

```
B = [x for x in len(A) if x[1] <= 30]
```

but it doesn't work, indeed. Any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `[item for item in A if item[1] < 30]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List filtering: list comprehension vs. lambda + filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013449/list-filtering-list-comprehension-vs-lambda-filter)

Comment: Thank you Chris. So the problem was actually the `len(A)` instead of just `A`?

Comment: @urgeo yes, in your case `x` is the index not the sublist itself

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
B = [x for x in A if x[1] <= 30]
```

Answer (score 2):

Your current code is attempting to generate an value to be used as an index at each iteration. To implement that approach, access each row of `A` with `x`:

```
B = [A[x] for x in range(len(A)) if A[x][1] <= 30]
```

Note, however, that is much simpler to use a list comprehension or the more functional `filter`:

List comprehension:

```
B = [i for i in A if i[1] <= 30]
```

`filter`:

```
B = list(filter(lambda x:x[1] <= 30, A))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a vectorised approach:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[0, 42, 2.6],
             [1, 20, 5.6],
             [2, 67, 3.5],
             [3, 12, 3.2],
             [4, 34, 1.1],
             [5, 74, 4.7],
             [6, 29, 2.9]])

A[A[:, 1] <= 30]

# array([[  1. ,  20. ,   5.6],
#        [  3. ,  12. ,   3.2],
#        [  6. ,  29. ,   2.9]])
```