# For Loop: output specific element in list within a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop

I am pretty new in python! Here below i have a list of 5 different strings.

```
afilelistawarded = ['123,456,789,12345,Correct,67890','a123,b456,c789,d12345,Correct,e67890','f123,g456,h789,i12345,Correct,j67890','k123,l456,m789,n12345,Correct,o67890','p123,q456,r789,s12345,Correct,t67890']

for i1 in afilelistawarded:
    for i2 in (afilelistawarded[i1]):
      del ((afilelistawarded[i1])[0])
      del ((afilelistawarded[i1])[1])
      del ((afilelistawarded[i1])[2])
      del ((afilelistawarded[i1])[3])
      del ((afilelistawarded[i1])[5])

print afilelistawarded
```

I am trying to output the following:

```
 afilelistawarded=['Correct','Correct','Correct','Correct','Correct']
```

How do i remove the unwanted items and output the correct strings to the same list?

Comment: Are correct elements always at the 5th place?

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013449/list-comprehension-vs-lambda-filter the question shows two options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure the 'Correct' always appears at `index=4`, you can simply use :

```
afilelistawarded = ['123,456,789,12345,Correct,67890','a123,b456,c789,d12345,Correct,e67890','f123,g456,h789,i12345,Correct,j67890','k123,l456,m789,n12345,Correct,o67890','p123,q456,r789,s12345,Correct,t67890']

for i1 in afilelistawarded:
    print i1.split(",")[4]
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
>>> afilelistawarded = ['123,456,789,12345,Correct,67890','a123,b456,c789,d12345,Correct,e67890','f123,g456,h789,i12345,Correct,j67890','k123,l456,m789,n12345,Correct,o67890','p123,q456,r789,s12345,Correct,t67890']
>>> [i.split()[4] for i in afilelistawarded]
['Correct', 'Correct', 'Correct', 'Correct', 'Correct']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, This should work, if you are sure about the position of the 'correct' element.

```
ls = []
filelistawarded = ['123,456,789,12345,Correct,67890','a123,b456,c789,d12345,Correct,e67890','f123,g456,h789,i12345,Correct,j67890','k123,l456,m789,n12345,Correct,o67890','p123,q456,r789,s12345,Correct,t67890']

for item in afilelistawarded:
           ls.append(item.split(',')[4])
```