# How create an array ommiting negative values from another array in python

Tags: python, filter

I need to create an array with the same data from another array but just the positive values.

I was trying this code below:

```
if a > 0:
    arr = a
```

Comment: If you Google the phrase "Python filter list", you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Comment: Yes, filter is the correct search term. This is also very popular to do with a list comprehension: `[a for a in arr if a > 0]`. Have a look at list comprehensions. They are very pythonic!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3013449/1358308 looks useful

Answer (score 0):

Here two possible options:

Option 1:
Initialize an empty list that is going to contain the array with positive numbers:

```
array1 = [1, 2, -1, -3, 5, 6, -9]

array2 = []
for item in array1:
    if item > 0:
        array2.append(item)
```

Option 2:

Use a list comprehension to create the second array:

```
array1 = [1, 2, -1, -3, 5, 6, -9]
array2 = [item for item in array1 if item > 0]
```

In both cases the output will be:

```
print(array2)
==> [1, 2, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Option 3: use `filter`; e.g. `filter(lambda item: item > 0, array1)`