# Order a dictionary's elements using lambda

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, dictionary

I'm trying to order the values in a dictionary. Each value is a tuple of the form `(element, [element,element...])`.

So if it looks like this:

```
{'5': (2, ['6']), '1': (3, ['4', '3']), '7': (3, ['9', '11', '12'])}
```

It should end up like this:

```
{'5': (2, ['6']), '1': (3, ['3', '4']), '7': (3, ['11', '12', '9'])}
```

The order is lexicographical string order, as you can see.

I tried to sort with a lambda but I cannot get to the list:

```
sortedDict = sorted(orderDict.values(),key=lambda x:x[0])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to return a sorted copy of `orderDict`, the answer by @jojo will work. To sort the dictionary in place without needing to make a copy, simply iterate over its values and sort them:

```
for v in orderDict.values():
    v[1].sort()
```

Note that you don't need to specify a `key`, since your lists are already made up of strings, which will be sorted as you expect. If your list *did* contain integers, you'd add `key=str`:

```
for v in orderDict.values():
    v[1].sort(key=str)
```

Comment: thank you for the comment. the thing is here if beside the str were all integers. does it will work also?

Comment: @LordNord I've added a note …

Answer (score 3):

You're almost there, what you want to do is use `sorted` on the 2nd element of the value with `key=str` (if you're not sure that your elements are always of type `str` already).

Also you don't need to use a `lambda`-expression for this.

**This can simply be done using [`dict` comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/)**:

```
d = {'5': (2, ['6']), '1': (3, ['4', '3']), '7': (3, ['9', '11', '12'])}

sorted_d = {k: (v0, sorted(v1, key=str)) for k, (v0, v1) in d.items()}
```

**If you want to do this in-place** then the [answer of @ZeroPiraeus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53895426/1622937) is the recommended way. As `sort` is an in-place operation you could, in principle, pack this in a list comprehension. *Note, however, that this is **not a recommended way** as you'll generate a list you're not using*:

```
In [38]: [v1.sort(key=str) for _, v1 in d.values()]                            
Out[38]: [None, None, None]
```

Comment: Thank you very much , if it's about time complexity, there is a difference of using lambda?

Comment: @LordNord There is no straight-forward answer to this. In some cases generators are faster, sometimes `lambda`-expressoins. This is a touchy subject in the python community, so I'll only point you to some discussions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013449/list-comprehension-vs-lambda-filter https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/list-comprehension-vs-map

Comment: Please do not use a list comprehension if you don't need the list produced. This is not idiomatic Python. Use a `for` loop instead.

Comment: @timgeb you are right, I should have stated more clearly that the for-loop is the recommended way. Adapted the answer.

Comment: @jojo thank you, I'm using the Zero Piraeus , for me it looks more readable, any way thank you very much for helping me, I'v learned something new.

Comment: @LordNord You are welcome! I understand that a for-loop looks easier to read and if you want to modify your existing dictionary and not create a new one, I also recommend you using the solutions of ZeroPiraeus. If you want to keep the original dictionary as it is and create a new, sorted one, then I'd recommend using my suggestion. Also, `list`- and `dict`- comprehension might seem hard at the beginning, but it is really useful, so I can only warmly recommend to try it out! :)

Comment: @jojo I should use them more, anyway they are useful, if I will get into this, It will be easier.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is using `dict.setdefault()`, as follows:

```
my_d = {'5': (2, ['6']), '1': (3, ['4', '3']), '7': (3, ['9', '11', '12'])}
new_d ={}
for n in my_d.keys():
    new_d.setdefault(n, (my_d[n][0], sorted(my_d[n][1])))

print new_d
```

Output:

```
{'1': (3, ['3', '4']), '5': (2, ['6']), '7': (3, ['11', '12', '9'])}
```