# Print only even number using lambda and map functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to print the even numbers by using only the lambda and map function. Not filter and any functions in python.

```
list(map(lambda x:x%2==0, range(20)))
```

OUTPUT:

```
[True, False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True, False]
```

Used the code like below

```
print(list(map(lambda x:x%2==0, range(20))))
```

I'm getting the boolean result but I need only even numbers. Is it possible by using a map function with lambda?

Comment: Isn't range a function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [list comprehension vs. lambda + filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013449/list-comprehension-vs-lambda-filter)

Comment: `list(range(0, 20, 2))` would do the trick. Without even `map` or `lambda`.

Comment: Sorry, assuming your instructor wants you to use only `map` and `lambda`, this isn't a duplicate.

Comment: Also, you cannot write `map` in terms of `filter` or viceversa. If you are logically doing `filter` use that. Or the equivalent comprehension. With `lambda` you can do pretty much anything as that is just an unnamed function. But then the *"do not use any functions"* requirement becomes a bit iffy. Perhaps you want to add a bit more context to your question.

Comment: `list(map(lambda x: x * 2, range(10)))`

Comment: Is `[True, False] * 10` allowed? It doesn't use any of the banned functions because it doesn't use any functions at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the set of even integers by doubling every element of the set of integers.  So all positive even integers less than n would be

```
n = 20
list(map(lambda n: n*2, range(n//2)))
# [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the filter method instead of map

```
list(filter(lambda x:x%2==0, range(1,20)))
```

Answer (score 0):

@Patrick Haugh's answer is better, but you can also do it with a list comprehension to filter for you. My code is somewhat terrible because this isn't what `map` is for!

```py
[x[1] for x in map(lambda x: (not x % 2, x), range(20)) if x[0]]
```

Please don't actually use this code for anything; use @norok2's comment instead. I wrote this for the challenge to myself and I wanted to see if it could be done, not because it's good.

```
list(range(0, 20, 2))
```