# Filter list of dates by year, month or day

Tags: python, list, date, filter

How a list of datetime.date objects can be filtered by specific year, month or day?

Example:

```py
import datetime as dt

dates = [dt.date(2017, 5, 6), dt.date(2015, 5, 13), dt.date(2012, 12, 6), dt.date(2017, 12, 6)]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [list comprehension vs. lambda + filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013449/list-comprehension-vs-lambda-filter)

Comment: No, my question is specifically for date filtering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import datetime as dt

dates = [dt.date(2017, 5, 6), dt.date(2015, 5, 13), dt.date(2012, 12, 6), dt.date(2017, 12, 6)]

# Filter by year
dates_2017 = list(filter(lambda x: x.year == 2017, dates))

# Filter by month
dates_may = list(filter(lambda x: x.month == 5, dates))

# Filter by day
dates_6th = list(filter(lambda x: x.day == 6, dates))
```