# Loop over List of tuples with one index of the tuple fixed

Tags: python, list

I'd like to loop over a list of tuples but having one of the indexes fixed with a determined value, like say we have this list:

```
myList = [(1,2,3) , (1,2,2), (2,3,4), (3,4,5), (1,3,4), (4,5,6), (4,6,8)]
```

and i wanted to loop over it fixing my first index with the value **1**, so in the loop I would be accessing those, and only those, values:

```
[(1,2,3), (1,2,2), (1,3,4)]
```

I know I can do this:

```
    newList = []
    for item in myList:
        if item[0] == 1:
            newList.append(item)
```

and then loop over this new list, but is there a direct or more perfomatic way of doing this?!

Comment: Do you have to do this for the same list several times with different first-values?

Comment: Your way is as performant as it's going to get, it's an O(N) algorithm which is the best you can do. Are you actually seeing performance issues?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga No, no, maybe I should had reformuled my question. Once I heard from a Profesor "If Python has something implemented then use it" (Maybe the best rephrase for english is "If Python has a built-in function for what you want, then use it"), so I was looking for a built-in method for that.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this:

```
new_list = [item for item in myList if item[0] == 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also uso [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) with a lambda. One benefit of this approach is that it returns a generator, so you do not need to instantiate the full filtered list (for example, if you only need the data to do subsequent processing).

```
>>> list(filter(lambda x: x[0] == 1, myList))
[(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 2), (1, 3, 4)]
```

Comment: In general, `filter` is not recommended. Same with `map`, these constructs are almost always better as list/dict/set comprehensions or generator expressions (and will be slightly faster usually). If you want lazy evaluation, you can use a generator expression.

Comment: I'm just highlighting another approach given that @myke already mentioned a conditional list comp.  The topic of list comprehensions vs lambda + filter is discussed in detail here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013449/list-comprehension-vs-lambda-filter

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehension to simplify your code:

```
tuples = [(1,2,3) , (1,2,2), (2,3,4), (3,4,5), (1,3,4), (4,5,6), (4,6,8)]

filtered_tuples = [t for t in tuples if t[0] == 1]

for t in filtered_tuples:
    # code here
```