# When would using the filter function be used instead of a list comprehension?

Tags: python, list, filter, list-comprehension

Recently, I have learned a bit about the filter method, an alternative to using list comprehensions.

Say I have a list as such:

```
names = ["Bob", "Billy", "Samuel", "Adam", "Rob"]
```

Now, I would like to get a list containing the names that start with the letter, "B". I could go about this in a couple of ways. This is one:

```
b_starting_names = list(filter(lambda name: name.startswith("B"), names))
```

This is another:

```
b_starting_names = [name for name in names if name.startswith("B")]
```

Could someone please explain what the difference is between a list comprehension and the filter function, and why someone may want to use one over the other?

Comment: They are equivalent, it is a question of style. List comprehensions are for conveniently expressing mapping/filtering operations. For what it's worth, Guido wanted to remove `map` and `filter` because the language had comprehensions.

Comment: Different versions of python had different style preferences and performance characteristics for comprehensions vs `filter`. Now it is mainly personal preference.

Comment: For me, I would only ever use `filter` if I already had some predicate function handy, so then my code becomes `list(filter(predicate, iterable))`,  which is readable and concise enough. If I ever would have to write `filter(lambda x: <expression involving x>, iterable)` then I would *always* just use `[x for x in iterable if <expression involving x>]` it is simply much more clear to my eyes. Same with `map`. So, I might use map if I want to do something like `for x in map(int, iterable): ...` since that is nice and tidy. Otherwise, comprehension.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga good thing Guido remembered the "Benevolent" part of BDFL.  Can you imagine how much code would need to be reworked if `map` and `filter` were removed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List comprehension vs. lambda + filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013449/list-comprehension-vs-lambda-filter)

Comment: @MarkRansom this was in the 2->3 transition, so the idea was that there was already going to be major changes. But yes, I think enough LISPers complained :). Personally, I find use for both from time to time, again, when I already have the function/callable handy.

Comment: The list comprehension vs. lambda + filter answered part of my question. However, I intended for my question to be more general, as the filter function can also be called using existing functions that have been declared previously.

Comment: FWIW: [The fate of reduce() in Python 3000
 by Guido van Rossum](https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no harm in using either. A similar comment can be made about `map`.

I tend to use whatever one feels easier to read. In your case I would avoid using the lambda as it is a bit verbose, and instead use the comprehension.

I would use `filter` or `map` methods if I already had a function existing I could just pass to the method, which would be more terse than the comprehension.

For example, say I write a program for finding the length of the largest name:

```
# Using map
longest = max(map(len, names))

# Using generator expression
longest = max(len(name) for name in names))
```

In the above example I would choose `map` over the generator expression, but it's entirely personal preference.

Comment: Technically I think that's a generator rather than a list comprehension.

Comment: @MarkRansom Hmm, I always called them list/ dict/ set/ generator comprehensions, but I guess the right term here is generator expression.

Comment: Yes, that is a generator expression. Note, although you might think that the generator expression is more performant, in my experience, the size of the iterable has to be quite large before it beats the list comprehension. And that I think is that creating lists and iterating over them is something Python does very fast. I use it because it *looks* nicer