# Find the string from a list that contains multiple patterns

Tags: python, string, match, list-comprehension

```
str_list = ['Alex is a good boy',
            'Ben is a good boy',
            'Charlie is a good boy']
matches = ['Charlie','good']
```

I want to return the third element in `str_list`, because it contains both 'Charlie' and 'good'.

I have tried:

```
[s for s in str_list if all([m in s for m in matches])][0]
```

But this seems overly verbose to me. More elegant solution please.

---

Based on the answer and comments below, we have:

`next(s for s in str_list if all(m in s for m in matches))`

It's obviously faster (however marginally) and neater.

Comment: Your solution looks pretty elegent to me!

Comment: Minor point: You can drop the brackets inside `all(...)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use the `filter` function, it returns an iterator so it stops at first match if used with `next`

```py
next(filter(lambda s: all(m in s for m in matches), str_list))
```

An even clearer method suggested by @Timus

```py
next(s for s in str_list if all(m in s for m in matches))
```

Comment: Nice use of `next`. But wouldn't `next(s for s in str_list if all(m in s for m in matches))` be more pythonic?

Comment: I like that too! Seems to be a big debate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013449/list-comprehension-vs-lambda-filter

Comment: I'd say that [Guido van Rossum](https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196) - Python creator - has settled that dabate :)): _"About 12 years ago, Python aquired lambda, reduce(), filter() and map(), courtesy of (I believe) a Lisp hacker who missed them and submitted working patches. But, despite of the PR value, I think these features should be cut from Python 3000."_

Comment: @Timus if you add an answer with `next(s for s in str_list if all(m in s for m in matches))`, I will mark it. That's exactly what I had in mind vaguely but failed to formulate explicitly.

Comment: @JingweiYu Thanks! I'd prefer if you would mark Mandera's anwer. The `next` is from him. Maybe he could add the version in my comment to the answer.