# How to generate a dictionary with nth number of keys and letters in sequential order?

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to generate a dictionary in the following format:

```
x = 3 #number of keys
y = 2 #number of key values (letters in sequential order)
```

The desired output is:

```
{1:[a, b],2:[c, d],3:[e,f]}
```

As a note, I am able to generate a list in range of letters in the following way:

```
list(map(chr, range(97, 98 + 3)))
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

However, I am struggling to figure out the rest.

Comment: For some added context to the replies so far. List comprehensions are favored more than map as being able to more easily be read and more pythonic, see [here](https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/readability/using_map_or_filter_where_list_comprehension_is_possible.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3013722/8508004). The dictionary comprehensions used in two of the proposed answers are the dictionary-generating versions of the list comprehension.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use an iterator:

```py
x, y = 3, 2

letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
# or whatever method you prefer, like what you proposed:
# letters = map(chr, range(97, 97 + 26))

letters_iter = iter(letters)
output = {k+1: [next(letters_iter) for _ in range(y)] for k in range(x)}
print(output) # {1: ['a', 'b'], 2: ['c', 'd'], 3: ['e', 'f']}
```

This assumes that `x` times `y` does not exceed 26. If you want to make the letters to cycle, then you can use `itertools.cycle` instead of `iter`:

```py
from itertools import islice, cycle
from string import ascii_lowercase

x, y = 3, 2

letters_iter = cycle(ascii_lowercase)
output = {k+1: [*islice(letters_iter, y)] for k in range(x)}
print(output) # {1: ['a', 'b'], 2: ['c', 'd'], 3: ['e', 'f']}
```

(Here, I used `islice` to shorten the inner list comprehension further. The star `*` in `[*...]` is (generalized) [unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/). Also I used `string.ascii_lowercase`, but any other ways would work.)

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. So let's have a discrete function like this:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as LC

def make_dict(x, y):
    return {k+1:list(LC[k*y:(k+1)*y]) for k in range(x)}

print(make_dict(3, 2))
```

**Output:**

```
{1: ['a', 'b'], 2: ['c', 'd'], 3: ['e', 'f']}
```