# lambda in nested loop with condition

Tags: python, loops, lambda, nested, logic

I encountered this question in one of my test for applying a new job.

Given this array :

`arr = [[-1, 1, 2, -2, 6], [3, 4, -5]]`

1. For each element in the list, if negative value is found, we want to exclude it
2. Square the remaining value

I already made an answer using normal looping

```
for i in arr:
    for j in range(len(i)):
        if i[j]>0:
            asd = i[j]**2
            i[j] = asd
        else:
            i.remove(i[j])
print(arr)
```

The result should be like this : `[[1, 4, 36], [9, 16]]`

The problem is, I have to use **lambda** function to deliver the question.

I tried to use nested loop with condition for lambda but it's very confusing. Any idea how to solve the problem ? Any helps will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Please update your question with your code that uses a `lambda` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you **need to use lambda**, you can convert what you would get as list comprehension (the most pythonic IMO):

```
[[x**2 for x in l if x>=0] for l in arr]
```

into a functional variant:

```
list(map(lambda l: list(map(lambda x: x**2, filter(lambda x: x>=0, l))), arr))
```

longer, less efficient, more cryptic, but you do have plenty of lambdas ;)

output: `[[1, 4, 36], [9, 16]]`

More on this topic: [list comprehension vs lambda+`filter`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013449/list-comprehension-vs-lambda-filter)

Answer (score 1):

How about using a list comprehension?

```
list_ = [[-1, 1, 2, -2, 6], [3, 4, -5]]

result = [[n*n for n in e if n >= 0] for e in list_]

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[[1, 4, 36], [9, 16]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lambda` like this:

```
arr = [[-1, 1, 2, -2, 6], [3, 4, -5]]

result = lambda nested_list: [[a ** 2 for a in b if a > 0] for b in nested_list]

print(result(arr))

>>> [[1, 4, 36], [9, 16]]
```

Comment: `lambda` should not assign to variables! ... that's why are called _anonymous_!

Answer (score 0):

one way of using `lambda`

```
>>> arr = [[-1, 1, 2, -2, 6], [3, 4, -5]]
>>> function = lambda x: map(lambda j:j**2, filter(lambda y: y>0, x))
>>> result = list(map(lambda x: list(function(x)), arr))
>>> result
[[1, 4, 36], [9, 16]]
```

Comment: @cards yes you were right, i did messed up

Answer (score 0):

A bit more verbose: the [`partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html) is not required but it is a bad practice to assign `lambda` to variable.

```
from functools import partial

power_2 = (2).__rpow__
is_positive = (0).__lt__

apply_to_row = partial(lambda row: list(map(power_2, filter(is_positive, row))))
out = list(map(apply_to_row, arr))
```

or a single line

```
out = list(map(lambda row: list(map(power_2, filter(is_positive, row))), arr))
```