# get only one value in element in array of elements python

Tags: python, arrays, json

I have this sample return json:

```
message_response_json = {"details": [
    {
        "orderId": "1",
        "accountId": "1",
        "orderStatus": "CANCELED"
    },
    {
        "orderId": "2",
        "accountId": "1",
        "orderStatus": "SETTLED"
    },
    {
        "orderId": "3",
        "accountId": "1",
        "orderStatus": "FUNDED"
    },
    {
        "orderId": "4",
        "accountId": "1",
        "orderStatus": "FUNDED"
    },
]}
```

I want to only get the list of `orderIds` with the `orderStatus` `"FUNDED"`. This is the code I have so far:

```
details = message_response_json['details']
results = list(filter(lambda detail: detail['orderStatus'].lower() == "funded", details))

print('results', results)
```

This is what's printing:

```
results [{'orderId': '3', 'accountId': '1', 'orderStatus': 'FUNDED'}, {'orderId': '4', 'accountId': '1', 'orderStatus': 'FUNDED'}]
```

But I only ever want to get something like:

```
results [{'orderId': '3'}, {'orderId': '4'}]
```

or

```
results ['3', '4']
```

Is there a built-in `map` function that I can use in python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use list-comprehension:

```py
out = [
    m["orderId"]
    for m in message_response_json["details"]
    if m["orderStatus"] == "FUNDED"
]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
['3', '4']
```

---

Or:

```py
out = [
    {"oderId": m["orderId"]}
    for m in message_response_json["details"]
    if m["orderStatus"] == "FUNDED"
]
print(out)
```

for:

```
[{'oderId': '3'}, {'oderId': '4'}]
```

Comment: Is this better than using filter and map?

Comment: @ProsyArceno That's opinion based. Myself I prefer list-comprehension. But for more discussion visit here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013449/list-comprehension-vs-lambda-filter

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use map and filter you can do

```
print(list(map(lambda s: {'orderId': s.get('orderId')}, filter(lambda s: s.get('orderStatus').lower() == 'funded', message_response_json.get('details')))))
```

It will filter details by status and then map them to wanted output