# Iterate on values/key pairs in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-re

I'm learning Python. I know how to do this in JavaScript but I lack the syntax-knowledge at this very moment nor can I find examples that tell me how to do this.

I have the following Array of Objects:

```
john_williams_compositions = [
    {"year": 1973, "Title": "The Poseidon Adventure", "type": "Best Orignal Score", "status": "nominated"},
    {"year": 1974, "Title": "Cinderella Liberty", "type": "Best Original Score", "status": "nominated"},
    {"year": 1974, "Title": "Tom Sawyer", "type": "Best Original Score", "status": "nominated"},
    {"year": 1975, "Title": "Earthquake", "type": "Best Original Score", "status": "nominated"},
    {"year": 1976, "Title": "Jaws", "type": "Best Original Score", "status": "Won"},
    {"year": 1978, "Title": "Close Encounters of the Third Kind", "type": "Best Original Score", "status": "nominated"},
    {"year": 1978, "Title": "Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope", "type": "Best Original Score", "status": "Won"},
    {"year": 1979, "Title": "Superman", "type": "Best Original Score", "status": "nominated"},
    {"year": 1981, "Title": "Star WArs: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back", "type": "Best Original Score", "status": "nominated"},
    {"year": 1983, "Title": "E.T. the Extra Terrestrial", "type": "Best Original Score", "status": "Won"},
    {"year": 1983, "Title": "If We Were in Love", "type": "Best Original Song", "status": "nominated"},
    {"year": 1985, "Title": "The River", "type": "Best Original Score", "status": "nominated"},
    {"year": 1988, "Title": "Empire of the Sun", "type": "Best Original Score", "status": "nominated"}
    ]
```

Now I want to get all the objects with the status `"Won"` in a new array.

I came up with this myself:

```
def won(list):
    result = []
    for x in list:
        if x.status == "Won":
            result.append[i]
    return result

print(won(john_williams_compositions))
```

Can anyone jumpstart me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x` is a `dict`. Unlike Javascript (I gather), there is a syntactic difference between access the value for a given key in a `dict` and accessing the value of an attribute.

```
x["foo"]  # Value associated with key "foo"
x.foo  # Value associated with the attribute "foo"
```

Your loop requires the former:

```
def won(list):
    result = []
    for x in list:
        if x["status"] == "Won":
            result.append[i]
    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this very easily with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
def won(lst):
    return [comp for comp in lst if comp['status'] == 'Won']


print(won(john_williams_compositions))
```

Or, alternatively, you can use the [`filter()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter):

```
def won(lst):
    return list(filter(lambda comp: comp['status'] == 'Won', lst))


print(won(john_williams_compositions))
```

Comment: And what method is preferred? And if one is, why?

Comment: @Wolk9 It's really up to you, however, I prefer using list comprehensions because they're easier to write. Also, sometimes list comprehensions are a bit faster because it doesn't need to call a lambda function every iteration.

Comment: @Wolk9 If you'd like to investigate the differences even more, you can read some of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013449/list-comprehension-vs-lambda-filter).

Answer (score 1):

You just need to iterate over the list (of dictionaries) then select those where the `status` key is equal to `Won`.

Probably best to write a function that will handle any status value. Something like this:

```py
john_williams_compositions = [
    {"year": 1973, "Title": "The Poseidon Adventure", "type": "Best Orignal Score", "status": "nominated"},
    {"year": 1974, "Title": "Cinderella Liberty", "type": "Best Original Score", "status": "nominated"},
    {"year": 1974, "Title": "Tom Sawyer", "type": "Best Original Score", "status": "nominated"},
    {"year": 1975, "Title": "Earthquake", "type": "Best Original Score", "status": "nominated"},
    {"year": 1976, "Title": "Jaws", "type": "Best Original Score", "status": "Won"},
    {"year": 1978, "Title": "Close Encounters of the Third Kind", "type": "Best Original Score", "status": "nominated"},
    {"year": 1978, "Title": "Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope", "type": "Best Original Score", "status": "Won"},
    {"year": 1979, "Title": "Superman", "type": "Best Original Score", "status": "nominated"},
    {"year": 1981, "Title": "Star WArs: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back", "type": "Best Original Score", "status": "nominated"},
    {"year": 1983, "Title": "E.T. the Extra Terrestrial", "type": "Best Original Score", "status": "Won"},
    {"year": 1983, "Title": "If We Were in Love", "type": "Best Original Song", "status": "nominated"},
    {"year": 1985, "Title": "The River", "type": "Best Original Score", "status": "nominated"},
    {"year": 1988, "Title": "Empire of the Sun", "type": "Best Original Score", "status": "nominated"}
    ]

def get_by_status(lst, status):
    result = []

    for d in lst:
        if d.get('status') == status:
            result.append(d)
            
    return result

print(get_by_status(john_williams_compositions, 'Won'))
```

Output:

```
{'year': 1976, 'Title': 'Jaws', 'type': 'Best Original Score', 'status': 'Won'}, {'year': 1978, 'Title': 'Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope', 'type': 'Best Original Score', 'status': 'Won'}, {'year': 1983, 'Title': 'E.T. the Extra Terrestrial', 'type': 'Best Original Score', 'status': 'Won'}]
```

**Note:** `get_by_status()` could be implemented as a list comprehension in one line of code. As OP is obviously a beginner, it's written this way for clarity.

```
def get_by_status(lst, status):
    return [d for d in lst if d.get('status') == status]
```

Comment: I'm curious at the one line solution. I'm a beginner with python, yet not with programming. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are a beginner and list comprehension might not look very sraightforward to you, here is a simple implementation:

```
def won(list):
    result = []
    for x in list:
        if x['status'] == 'Won':
            print(x['status'])
            result.append(x)
    return result

print(won(john_williams_compositions))
```