# Python Challenge #2 - For loop problem

Tags: python, for-loop

[Python Challenge #2](http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/ocr.html)

[Answer I found](http://ymcagodme.blogspot.com/2011/04/python-challenge-level-2.html)

```
FILE_PATH = 'l2-text'
f = open(FILE_PATH)
print ''.join([ t for t in f.read() if t.isalpha()])
f.close()
```

Question: Why is their a 't' before the for loop `t for t in f.read()`.
I understand the rest of the code except for that one bit.
If I try to remove it I get an error, so what does it do?

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the quick replies and your time, it's greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[t for t in f.read() if t.isalpha()]` is a list comprehension. Basically, it takes the given iterable (`f.read()`) and forms a list by taking all the elements read by applying an optional filter (the `if` clause) and a mapping function (the part on the left of the `for`).

However, the mapping part is trivial here, this makes the syntax look a bit redundant: for each element `t` given, it just adds the element value (`t`) to the output list. But more complex expressions are possible, for example `t*2 for t ...` would duplicate all valid characters.

Comment: Thank you for the simplified answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is a [list comprehension](http://www.python.org/doc//current/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), not a `for`-loop.

> List comprehensions provide a concise way to create lists.

```
[t for t in f.read() if t.isalpha()]
```

This creates a [`list`](http://www.python.org/doc//current/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) of all of the `alpha` characters in the file (`f`). You then [`join()`](http://www.python.org/doc//current/library/string.html#string.join) them all together.

You now have a link to the documentation, which should help you comprehend comprehensions. It's tricky to search for things when you don't know what they're called!

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and helping me.

Answer (score 0):

note the following is also valid:

```
print ''.join(( t for t in f.read() if t.isalpha()))
```

instead of [ and ] you have ( and )
This specifies a generator instead of a list.
[generator comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364802/generator-comprehension)

Comment: The second parens are unnecessary to create a generator expression: `''.join(t for t in f)` is perfectly valid

Comment: Ah, thanks yeah I've learnt a lot more about python since then