# What's the difference between lists enclosed by square brackets and parentheses in Python?

Tags: python, list, tuples

```
>>> x=[1,2]
>>> x[1]
2
>>> x=(1,2)
>>> x[1]
2
```

Are they both valid? Is one preferred for some reason?

Comment: Just FYI: there's a more profound difference between `(i for i in ...)` and `[i for i in ...]`.

Comment: @RikPoggi What is the profound difference? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: The first one is a **generator expression** and the second one is a **list comprehension**. You can found some informations here: [Official Tutorial on List Comprehension](http://docs.python.org/py3k/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), [PEP 289](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/). And here in some OS questions: [Generator Expressions vs. List Comprehension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789/generator-expressions-vs-list-comprehension), [generator-comprehension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364802/generator-comprehension).

Answer (score 330, accepted):

Square brackets are [lists](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) while parentheses are [tuples](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences).

A list is mutable, meaning you can change its contents:

```
>>> x = [1,2]
>>> x.append(3)
>>> x
[1, 2, 3]
```

while tuples are not:

```
>>> x = (1,2)
>>> x
(1, 2)
>>> x.append(3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'append'
```

The other main difference is that a tuple is hashable, meaning that you can use it as a key to a dictionary, among other things. For example:

```
>>> x = (1,2)
>>> y = [1,2]
>>> z = {}
>>> z[x] = 3
>>> z
{(1, 2): 3}
>>> z[y] = 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

---

Note that, as many people have pointed out, you can add tuples together. For example:

```
>>> x = (1,2)
>>> x += (3,)
>>> x
(1, 2, 3)
```

However, **this does not mean tuples are mutable**. In the example above, a *new* tuple is constructed by adding together the two tuples as arguments. The original tuple is not modified. To demonstrate this, consider the following:

```
>>> x = (1,2)
>>> y = x
>>> x += (3,)
>>> x
(1, 2, 3)
>>> y
(1, 2)
```

Whereas, if you were to construct this same example with a list, `y` would also be updated:

```
>>> x = [1, 2]
>>> y = x
>>> x += [3]
>>> x
[1, 2, 3]
>>> y
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: good yet simple examples to list out the differences. Thanks!

Comment: for the above 'y=x' example , list and tuple behave in the same way now (verified in python3.8.5)

Answer (score 14):

One interesting difference :

```
lst=[1]
print lst          // prints [1]
print type(lst)    // prints <type 'list'>

notATuple=(1)
print notATuple        // prints 1
print type(notATuple)  // prints <type 'int'>
                                         ^^ instead of tuple(expected)
```

A comma must be included in a tuple even if it contains only a single value. e.g. `(1,)` instead of `(1)`.

Comment: Thank you.  This is what I was looking for.  The code I saw had a (list1 + list2 + list3) and it returned a list, not a tuple.

Answer (score 4):

They are not lists, they are a list and a tuple. You can read about [tuples](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) in the Python tutorial.  While you can mutate lists, this is not possible with tuples.

```
In [1]: x = (1, 2)

In [2]: x[0] = 3
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

/home/user/<ipython console> in <module>()

TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way brackets and parentheses differ is that square brackets can describe a list comprehension, e.g. `[x for x in y]`

Whereas the corresponding parenthetic syntax specifies a tuple *generator*: `(x for x in y)`

You can get a tuple comprehension using: `tuple(x for x in y)`

See: [Why is there no tuple comprehension in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16940293/why-is-there-no-tuple-comprehension-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

The first is a list, the second is a tuple. Lists are mutable, tuples are not.

Take a look at the [Data Structures](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html) section of the tutorial, and the [Sequence Types](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq) section of the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Comma-separated items enclosed by  `(` and `)` are `tuple`s, those enclosed by `[` and `]` are `list`s.

Comment: There are no lists that are enclosed by "round" brackets, they are tuples!  But you probably mean the right thing. `:P`

Comment: _Lists enclosed by ( and ) are tuples_ .. I'm confused, are they lists or tuples?

Comment: @julio.alegria I think what @FlopCoder meant to write was "**Items** enclosed by `(` and `)` are `tuple`s, those enclosed by `[` and `]` are `list`s."

Answer (score 0):

( thanx [Robert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1431720/robert) for clarification, below is only in case of using listcomprehensions : )

! another **very important difference** is that with round brackets we will have a generator and so the **memory consumption is much lower** in comparison to list with square brackets
esspecially when you deal with big lists - **generator** will eat not only significantly less memory but also **will take much less time** 'cause you will not need to prebuilt objects in list

Comment: Are you sure om that? Can you [edit] your answer and explain more why there is a generator? All other answers say that `(...)` is a tuple vs `[...]` being a list. AFAIK a generator is a function, but the questions has constants.