# Bar graph for male and female born on particular date/time

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I need to draw a bar graph for the values:

```
 male=('2', '1', '2', '6', '6', '1') # list may increase
 time=('Tue_Aug_13_04:37:40_2013', 'Mon_Jul__1_02:33:11_2013','Tue_Aug_13_04:37:40_2013', 'Thu_Jul__4_01:53:32_2013', 'Mon_Jul__1_10:05:55_2013','Mon_Jul__1_04:15:25_2013')# list may increase
female=(16, 11, 16, 12, 12, 11) # list may increase
```

Male in green colour, female in red colour as the image attached below:

[image: example-plot]

The code which I tried:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse, Polygon

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(131)
ax1.bar(male, color='red', edgecolor='black')
ax1.bar(bottom=range(female), color='blue', edgecolor='black')
ax1.set_xticks(time)
plt.show()
```

What modifications do I need to make in order to draw the bar graph as shown in the image attached for my values?

Comment: What do you want to do with the `time`? What should be your `x`-axis? Does [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902371/matplotlib-bar-chart-with-dates) help?

Comment: Hi Schorsch,Time should be in x-axis and y axis as both male and female count with different colour with count dispalyed on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.) I **strongly** suggest that you familiarize yourself with the python syntax:

- [What's the difference between lists enclosed by square brackets and parentheses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900166/whats-the-difference-between-lists-enclosed-by-square-brackets-and-parentheses)
- [What's the difference between `'2'` and `2`?](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_variable_types.htm)

2.) Make use of [the matplotlib documentation](http://matplotlib.org/index.html) to figure out the correct syntaxt for the plot commands you are using.

3.) In this particular case: To get you going, change your data to:

```
male=[2, 1, 2, 6, 6, 1] # list may increase  
time=['Tue_Aug_13_04:37:40_2013', 'Mon_Jul__1_02:33:11_2013','Tue_Aug_13_04:37:40_2013', 'Thu_Jul__4_01:53:32_2013', 'Mon_Jul__1_10:05:55_2013','Mon_Jul__1_04:15:25_2013']# list may increase  
female=[16, 11, 16, 12, 12, 11] # list may increase
```

Please examine carefully what has changed.

4.) The `bar` command you try to call has not enough input arguments. With the changed data from above, try this:

```
ax1.bar(range(len(time)),male,width=0.5, color='red', edgecolor='black')
ax1.bar(range(len(time)),female,width=0.5,bottom=male,color='blue', edgecolor='black')
```

What has changed?

- you need the following inputs: `left, height, width=0.8`
- you had only one of those
- due to the fact that your dates are given as strings, you need a generic counter for the `x`-axis, hence the `range(len(time))` to provide as many tics as there are entries in `time`.
- now, you specify the `height` according to the values in `male` and `female` - none of which should be strings!
- define a `width`
- in your case, you want the bars to be stacked - therefore, specify the first set of values as `bottom` for the second

4.) Because `time` is made up of strings, you cannot use it for the ticks. Instead, try:

```
ax1.set_xticklabels(time,rotation=90)
```

Here, you use the strings from `time` as tick-**labels**. The `rotation=90` is a nice feature so that the long strings do not overlap.

5.) If the labels are cut off by the plot window, try this:

```
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

This should get you back on track.

---

Good key words for a web-search inlcude:

- matplotlib stacked bar
- matplotlib tick labels rotation
- matplotlib ticks date

Comment: I am very new to this matplotlib, thank you very much for the help, I will go through the documentation...