# Python, one line if, else or statement?

Tags: python, if-statement

I am well aware that you can do a one line `if else` statement in Python, but I am wondering if it is possible to add an `or` to that.  For some reason this does not work, even though it reads like it should.  Is there any way to do this:

```
def write(value):
    return 'That is not a good value' if value is not 1 or 0 #SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**EDIT**

So that this function would check if the passed in value was the integer 0 or 1, return `'That is not a good value'` if it is not, or not return anything if it is.  I.E.

```
write(1) #Nothing
write(2) # That is not a good value
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? This isn't exactly easy to read and forces a person to read the whole line to understand what it's trying to do.

Comment: I can't even tell what you're trying to do after reading the whole line.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Python have a ternary conditional operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator)

Comment: The biggest problem is that you have no `else`.  It's never legal to have an `if-else` expression without an `else` part; the `or` doesn't enter into it.  It's an *expression*, not a *statement*, and therefore it must have a defined *value*.

Comment: The reason I asked this was that that question only covers `if else` or the ternary condition.  This question has a third condition

Comment: I'm sorry Mark, I don't quite understand what you mean.

Comment: This question has no `else` condition at all.  I don't even see two conditions, much less three.

Comment: Perhaps you can explain what value your expression should evaluate to for sample values of `value`. That way it would be easier to understand what you mean.

Comment: @Startec: what I mean is, your code has no `else`.  The word `else` appears nowhere in your code. You can't have an `if-else` statement without an `else`. Your code is an ex-`else`.  It has rung down the curtain and joined the choir invisible...

Comment: Ahh yes, now I see the confusion.  Originally I wanted to check if the value was 1 or 0. If it was not, I wanted to return the value. so I wanted to see is value 1? no! Okay so is the value 0? no! Then return the value.  However, the way the question was answered does make it sound like the ternary operator.

Comment: Regardless of what you're trying to do, you can't have an `if` expression without an `else`.    All expressions must have a value, and an `if` expression with no `else` part has no value in the case that the test is false.

Comment: @Startec the `1 or 0` part is just basic boolean logic that you got wrong. `value == 0 or value == 1` (or, more idiomatic, `value in (0, 1)`) is not the same as `value == 1 or 0`.

Comment: Based on your comment where you clarify your requirements (you should probably edit the question instead), there's one important question left unanswered: what exactly do you want to do when the value *is* 1 or 0?

Comment: The "clarification" actually contradicts the attempt in the question: The question implies `(0, 1)` are good values, whereas the comment says they're not (or why would they be returned?).

Comment: Thank you for asking for the clarification. Does my edit and example help?

Comment: @MarkReed I see your point.  Obviously I am a little confused here, because you are right, there is no else clause, I only want to return something if the passed in value is not one of those two values

Comment: As @MarkReed explained, an *expression* can't return nothing, it always must return something. You can always return `None` obviously, which is what a function without an explicit return value would return.

Comment: I see, I am using this inside of another function to see if the function should continue executing. It should, as long as the value is 1 or 0.  Do I need to explicitly add `True` in that case or does `None` work?

Comment: That of course depends on how you check the function's return value. If you check it like `if write(v) is None` you obviously need to use `None` as your sentinel value for `OK`. If you want to use `42` instead, you can do that too.

Comment: what happens if value is not 1 or 0

Comment: Thanks for this @LukasGraf, and basically I just want the function to `continue`.  I basically my idea was that if the `write` function returned something, the rest of the function would stop (i.e. the parent function). However, if the value was not 0 or 1, nothing would be returned so the parent function would finish.

Comment: `return value in {1,0} ` `if write(x)` continue in function

Comment: @Startec that's not how it works, at least not "automatically". Unless you check `write()`'s return value and act on it, the calling function doesn't care about whether it returns something or not. That kind of control flow that you describe could however be achieved by raising your own [exceptions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html). But this is way beyond getting an `if..else` on one line, you should really create a new question and explain everything that's relevant to your problem there.

Comment: Getting more code onto one line is not a good thing, BTW.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
'That is not a good value' if value not in (0, 1) else None
```

In the above, we can use the `in` membership operator to test the equivalent of an `or`expression with two or more conditions. Notice that a conditional expression *must* have an `else` part (see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions)). If you don't want to return "anything" you still have to return *something*. For instance, the empty string `''` or `None`.

Comment: I think the `is` is not needed here, the logic doesn't really call for testing the *identity* of the objects (not the downvoter though)

Comment: To me this syntax is very succinct and not too long, however, I can see based on the comments not everyone feels that way. Is this not "Pythonic"?

Comment: I was going to comment that this is the way to do it, but to @Startec, yes, this is the *Pythonic* way to do it. If you want ternary operation, you require the else.

Comment: Why use a tuple instead of a list here? Is it just faster?

Comment: Yes, tuples are faster than lists. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26556410/what-to-pass-when-passing-arguments-where-a-list-or-tuple-is-required/26556568#26556568

Answer (score 3):

There's two problems.

1. What should that code return if it isn't 0 or 1?
2. Your conditional is parsed as: `value is not (1 or 0)`
3. You really shouldn't compare numbers using `is`. Use `==` or `!=`.

Let's fix it.

```
def write(value):
    return 'That is not a good value' if value != 1 and value != 0 else 'Great value!'
```

Or, using a set for clarity:

```
def write(value):
    return 'That is not a good value' if value not in {0, 1} else 'Great value!'
```

And, we can see this now working here:

```
>>> def write(value):
...     return 'That is not a good value' if value not in {0, 1} else 'Great value!'
... 
>>> write(0)
'Great value!'
>>> write(1)
'Great value!'
>>> write(2)
'That is not a good value'
```

Comment: I don't like the use of `is` here, it seems like `!=` is the better comparison. `is` should only be used when we specifically want to test for identity

Comment: @Marius: I totally agree. I should have fixed that as well.