# Get number of items from list (or other iterable) with certain condition

Tags: python, list, count, functional-programming, sequence

Assuming that I have a list with a huge number of items,

```
l = [ 1, 4, 6, 30, 2, ... ]
```

I want to get the number of items from that list, where an item satisfies a certain condition. My first thought was:

```
count = len([i for i in l if my_condition(l)])
```

But if the filtered list also has a great number of items, I think that
creating a new list for the filtered result is just a waste of memory.  For efficiency, IMHO, the above call can't be better than:

```
count = 0
for i in l:
    if my_condition(l):
        count += 1
```

Is there any functional-style way to get the # of items that satisfy the condition without generating a temporary list?

Comment: The choice between generators and lists is a choice between execution time and memory consumption. You would be surprised how often the results are counter intuitive if you profile the code. Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Answer (score 152):

You can use a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions):

```
>>> l = [1, 3, 7, 2, 6, 8, 10]
>>> sum(1 for i in l if i % 4 == 3)
2
```

or even

```
>>> sum(i % 4 == 3 for i in l)
2
```

which uses the fact that `True == 1` and `False == 0`.

Alternatively, you could use `itertools.imap` (python 2) or simply `map` (python 3):

```
>>> def my_condition(x):
...     return x % 4 == 3
... 
>>> sum(map(my_condition, l))
2
```

Answer (score 32):

You want a [generator comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364802/generator-comprehension) rather than a list here.

For example,

```
l = [1, 4, 6, 7, 30, 2]

def my_condition(x):
    return x > 5 and x < 20

print sum(1 for x in l if my_condition(x))
# -> 2
print sum(1 for x in range(1000000) if my_condition(x))
# -> 14
```

Or use `itertools.imap` (though I think the explicit list and generator expressions look somewhat more Pythonic).

Note that, though it's not obvious from the `sum` example, you can compose generator comprehensions nicely.  For example,

```
inputs = xrange(1000000)      # In Python 3 and above, use range instead of xrange
odds = (x for x in inputs if x % 2)  # Pick odd numbers
sq_inc = (x**2 + 1 for x in odds)    # Square and add one
print sum(x/2 for x in sq_inc)       # Actually evaluate each one
# -> 83333333333500000
```

The cool thing about this technique is that you can specify conceptually separate steps in code without forcing evaluation and storage in memory until the final result is evaluated.

Answer (score 13):

This can also be done using `reduce` if you prefer functional programming

```
reduce(lambda count, i: count + my_condition(i), l, 0)
```

This way you only do 1 pass and no intermediate list is generated.

Answer (score 11):

you could do something like:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,..]
count = sum(1 for i in l if my_condition(i))
```

which just adds 1 for each element that satisfies the condition.

Answer (score 2):

```
from itertools import imap
sum(imap(my_condition, l))
```

Comment: `imap` is not available with current Python.