# Count how many values in a list that satisfy certain condition

Tags: python

I have the following list,

```
mylist = ['0.976850566018849',
 '1.01711066941038',
 '0.95545901267938',
 '1.13665822176679',
 '1.21770587184811',
 '1.12567451365206',
 '1.18041077035567',
 '1.13799827821001',
 '1.1624485106005',
 '1.37823533969271',
 '1.39598077584722',
 '1.23844320976322',
 '1.57397155911713',
 '1.40605782943842',
 '1.36037525085048',
 '1.185',
 '1.22795283469963',
 '1.17192311574904',
 '1.04121940463022',
 '1.0133517787145',
 '0.986161470813006',
 '1.09820439504488',
 '1.06640283661947',
 '1.05764772395448',
 '1.02678616758973',
 '1.01876057166248',
 '1.09019498604372',
 '1.1665479238629',
 '1.07170094763279',
 '1.1326945725342',
 '1.18199297460235',
 '1.20353001964446',
 '1.00973941850665',
 '1.0662943967844',
 '1.04876624296406',
 '1.12447065457189',
 '0.954629674212134',
 '1.02961694279098']
```

What I want to do is to count how many values in that list which is >= 1.3.
Returning 5, which is:

```
      '1.57397155911713' 
      '1.40605782943842'
      '1.36037525085048'
      '1.39598077584722' 
      '1.37823533969271'
```

Is there a compact way to do it in Python?

Comment: Why does it have to be compact?

Comment: What would be a _not-so-compact_ way to do so?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python: get number of items from list(sequence) with certain condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15375093/python-get-number-of-items-from-listsequence-with-certain-condition)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I take compactness, you mentioned in the question, as shorter code. So, I present

```
sum(float(num) >= 1.3 for num in mylist)
```

This takes advantage of the fact that, in python `True` values are taken as 1 and `False` as 0. So, whenever `float(num) >= 1.3` evaluates to Truthy, it will be `1` and if it fails, result would be 0. So, we add all the values together to get the total number of items which are greater than or equal to `1.3`.

You can check that like this

```
True == 1
# True
True + True
# 2
False * 10
# 0
```

Answer (score 7):

To count how many values in that list which is >= 1.3:

```
sum(1 for x in mylist if float(x) >= 1.3)
```

If you need to actually extract the list of numbers which satisfy the condition, just create that list with a list comprehension and do whatever you want with it:

```
a = [x for x in mylist if float(x) >= 1.3]
print a
print len(a)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions)

> Some simple generators can be coded succinctly as expressions using a
>   syntax similar to list comprehensions but with parentheses instead of
>   brackets. These expressions are designed for situations where the
>   generator is used right away by an enclosing function. **Generator
>   expressions are more compact** but less versatile than full generator
>   definitions and tend to be more memory friendly than equivalent list
>   comprehensions.

Something like this:

```
sum(1 for x in mylist if float(x) >= 1.3)
```

Comment: @thefourtheye Leaving the same _tip_ on every answer doesn't seem very constructive.  Might as well write an answer yourself.

Comment: @devnull Sorry about that, I ll remove them.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the values returned to you and stored in a list you could do:

```
count = []
for value in mylist:
    num = float(value)
    if num >= 1.3:
        count.append(value)
```

If you want it to output the list just add:

```
print(count)
```

or if you want the count of the number of values that are greater add:

```
print(len(count))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `numpy` or `pandas`, though for such a simple computation they would be much slower than the alternatives mentioned above.

Using [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/),

```
import numpy as np
arr=np.array(mylist).astype(float)
print len(arr[arr>=1.3])
```

Using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/),

```
import pandas as pd
s=pd.Series(mylist).astype(float)
print len(s[s>=1.3])
```

Alternatively,

```
(pd.Series(l).astype(float)>=1.3).value_counts()[True]
```

For performance, the fastest solution seems to be

```
In [51]: %timeit sum(1 for x in mylist if float(x) >= 1.3)
100000 loops, best of 3: 8.72 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative, using the `reduce()` builtin:

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x + (y >= 1.3), mylist, 0)
```

Just for completeness, since I see there's already an accepted answer. The point is, there's often more than one way to accomplish something in Python (or many other languages, for that matter)...

Answer (score 0):

by using list comprehension

```
>>> len([i for i in mylist if float(i) >= 1.3])
```