# How do I print a specific range of numbers in a list? Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, integer, range

I've had a look at the similar questions asked on here but I can't seem to figure it out. I'm just starting out learning Python as one of my first programming languages and this is something I need to figure out how to do to move on with a task in my course.

```py
data = [90, 30, 13, 67, 85, 87, 50, 45, 51, 72, 64, 69, 59, 17, 22, 23, 44, 25, 16, 67, 85, 87, 50, 45, 51, 72, 59, 14, 50, 55, 32, 23, 24, 25, 37, 28, 39, 30, 33, 35, 40, 34, 41, 43, 94, 95, 98, 99, 44, 45, 47, 48, 49, 53, 61, 63, 69, 75, 77, 60, 83]
```

Here is my list of data, I need to print the **amount** of entries that are between 10 and 20 in the list (there are four)

All I can seem to do is print the 10th to the 20th entry in the list with this `print(data[10:20])` but this is not the information I need to extract.

Comment: [Count how many values in a list that satisfy certain condition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22904380/1324033)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like:

```
print(len([num for num in data if num <= 20 and num >= 10]))
```

You would use list comprehension to create a list with all numbers of the data-list that are in between 10 and 20 (10 and 20 included).

Then you take the length of that list and print it.

This creates the list of all numbers between 10 and 20:

```
 my_list_of_numbers = [num for num in data if num <= 20 and num >= 10]
```

**Edit**: If you actually want to sum all the numbers that are between 10 and 20, you could do the following:

```
print(sum([num for num in data if num <= 20 and num >= 10]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sum` here.

```
sum(1 for num in data if 10<=num<=20)
# 4
```

You can just do this

```
sum(10 <= num <= 20 for num in data) @Austin's suggested this in the comments
```

Comment: While this is good, I would go with `sum(10 <= num <= 20 for num in data)` though might be unreadable for some.

Comment: @Austin Agreed, but worth adding. Edited the answer and added creds.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `list comprehension` :

```
data=[90,30,13,67,85,87,50,45,51,72,64,69,59,17,22,23,44,25,16,67,85,87,50,45,51,72,59,14,50,55,32,23,24,25,37,28,39,30,33,35,40,34,41,43,94,95,98,99,44,45,47,48,49,53,61,63,69,75,77,60,83]
L = [x for x in data if 10 <= x <= 20]
print(L)
# [13, 17, 16, 14]
print(len(L))
# 4
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want the amount of data:

```
data = [90,30,13,67,85,87,50,45,51,72,64,69,59,17,22,23,44,25,16,67,85,87,50,45,51,72,59,14,50,55,32,23,24,25,37,28,39,30,33,35,40,34,41,43,94,95,98,99,44,45,47,48,49,53,61,63,69,75,77,60,83]

datanew = (10 < x < 20 for x in data)

# print the amount of data
print(sum(datanew))
```

Output:

```
4
```

Comment: Fixed, the problem is not posed in the most correct way.

Answer (score 0):

```py
data = [90, 30, 13, 67, 85, 87, 50, 45, 51, 72, 64, 69, 59, 17, 22, 23, 44, 25, 16, 67, 85, 87, 50, 45, 51, 72, 59, 14, 50, 55, 32, 23, 24, 25, 37, 28, 39, 30, 33, 35, 40, 34, 41, 43, 94, 95, 98, 99, 44, 45, 47, 48, 49, 53, 61, 63, 69, 75, 77, 60, 83]

amount = 0

for x in range(9, 19):
    amount = amount + data[x]

print(amount)
```

maybe this answer can resolve your problem

Answer (score 0):

A simple for loop with a if statement will work.

```
data=[90,30,13,67,85,87,50,45,51,72,64,69,59,17,22,23,44,25,16,67,85,87,50,45,51,72,59,14,50,55,32,23,24,25,37,28,39,30,33,35,40,34,41,43,94,95,98,99,44,45,47,48,49,53,61,63,69,75,77,60,83]
count = 0
for number in data:
    if number <= 20 and number >= 10:
        count += 1
print(count)
```