# Count list/tuple elements which are different than variable?

Tags: python, list, count, element

I have list or/and tuple:

```
MyVar = [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0]
```

And I want to count elements in this which are different from `0`.

How to do that?

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15375093/python-get-number-of-items-from-listsequence-with-certain-condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a `sum` over a conditional generator expression which doesn't require any intermediate lists or unnecessary arithmetic operations:

```
>>> sum(1 for element in MyVar if element != 0)
1
```

or as pointed out by @Jean-François Fabre:

```
>>> sum(1 for element in MyVar if element)
1
```

In case the `MyVar` **only** contains numbers this counts the number of not-zero values.

Comment: or `sum(1 for element in MyVar if element)`

Comment: There is a subtle difference between "not zero" and "is truthy" - and the question asked for "not zero". In this case both would give the same result but they wouldn't if the list contains some weird values like empty strings/tuples/dicts/lists.

Answer (score 9):

No need to generate lists, just:

```
len(MyVar) - MyVar.count(0)
```

Answer (score 3):

Get the length of the sublist of all elements that are not 0

```
MyVar = [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0]
len([x for x in MyVar if x != 0])
>> 1
```

Comment: Probably not a good idea to use `is` or `is not` to compare values. It's just an implementation detail that `0` is a constant and it's only a constant in CPython.  `!=` would be better.

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
>>> len(filter(lambda x: x != 0, MyVar))
1
```

Comment: doesn't work in python 3. You don't have to pass an argument to filter. Just pass `None` BTW.: `len(list(filter(None,MyVar)))`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre good thing there isn't a python3 tag on this question :)

Comment: for me now answers should be python 3 compliant unless otherwise stated. python 2 is history.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre *"...unless otherwise stated"*.  As in, how there is specifically a python2.7 tag on this question...

Comment: okay, that was just a comment. The `filter(None,` part is interesting, you should try it, though.

Answer (score 2):

The following should work:

```
>>> MyVar = [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0]
>>> sum(map(bool, MyVar))
1
```

It will convert the list to a list of booleans, with value `True` iff an element is nonzero. Then it'll sum all elements by implicitly considering `True` having value 1 and `False` having value 0.

Comment: that for `MyVar = [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,3]` will return `1 + 3 = 4`

Comment: true. OP example isn't representative, as always :)

Answer (score 1):

Try with `filter()`:

```
>>> my_var = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> result = filter(lambda x: x > 0, my_var)
[1]
>>> print(len(result))
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Not nearly as efficient as any of the answers above, but simple and straight forward nonetheless

```
myVar = [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0]
count = 0

for var in myVar:
    if var != 0:
        count += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

With [reduce](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) from functools:

```
from functools import reduce

reduce((lambda x, y: x + (y>0)), MyVar, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
f = sum([1 for x in MyVar if x!= 0])
```

One line :)

Comment: should it be x for x in MyVar?

Comment: why? I am doing a sum

Comment: Well it wasn't me that down voted - but I just took a guess at why you received it.

Answer (score 0):

Using sum of iterator:

```
sum(x != 0 for x in MyVar)
```