# How to sum a list that contains dictionary elements

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am not sure if I am asking the question correctly but I mean the following:

Lets say I have dictionary

```
p = {'A' : 1, 'B' : 2, 'C' : 3}
```

then I have list

```
q = ['A', 'B']
```

how do I sum q so that the result is 3?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a fairly simple task; you should be able to do this if you know how to use a dictionary and how to loop over the elements of a list...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the built-in function `sum` and a generator expression:

```
>>> p = {'A' : 1, 'B' : 2, 'C' : 3}
>>> q = ['A','B']
#using generator expression
>>> sum(p.get(x,0) for x in q)
3
#using list comprehension, not memory efficient
>>> sum( [p.get(x,0) for x in q] )
3
```

In case any of the element in `q` is not found in `p` then `dict.get` will return the default value `0`, so no errors will be raised.

help on `dict.get`:

```
>>> print dict.get.__doc__
D.get(k[,d]) -> D[k] if k in D, else d.  d defaults to None.
```

The [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) version is roughly equivalent to:

```
sums = []
for x in q:                  #loop over each item in q            
    sums.append(p.get(x,0))  #fetch the value of item from p and append it to sums  
print sum(sums)              # sum the list sums
```

`(p.get(x,0) for x in q)` is a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator_expression), instead of generating whole list in memory it returns one value at a time.

```
summ = 0
for x in q:
    summ += p.get(x,0)
print summ
```

Comment: Sorry, Im a bit new to Python, can you explain what is happening? and thanks for the quick response!

Comment: Thank you!
now just one more quick question which I should have added in the main question, if you can answer it (sorry!)
my list actually has a pair of values
ex:
Pair1 = ("A", "B", "C")
Dict = {"E" : 1, "F" : 2, "G" : 3)
mylist = [AE, BF]
I want to sum the E and F solely to get 3

Comment: @user2444127 Don't move the goalposts on existing questions. While your new question is related, it's still a new problem, belongs in a separate question, and you should try working it out on your own first.

Comment: @user2444127 try something like : `sum(Dict.get(x[1],0) for x in mylist)`

Answer (score 4):

You can do

```
sum(p[k] for k in q)
```

This expression `p[k] for k in q` is a [generator comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364802/generator-comprehension)- similar to a [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk) except that it never has to construct the entire list (which makes it faster and more memory-efficient when all you need is the sum).

Note that this code is basically a more concise version of:

```
total = 0
for k in q:
    total = total + p[k]
```

Which might be a bit clearer to you.

Answer (score 3):

One way with functional programming and the [operator.itemgetter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) function:

```
>>> p = {'A' : 1, 'B' : 2, 'C' : 3}
>>> q = ['A', 'B']
>>> import operator
>>> sum(operator.itemgetter(*q)(p))
3
```

Comment: list comprehensions and generator expressions are still considered functional

Comment: sure, I guess I really meant without a for loop

Answer (score 2):

Another approach: Take advantage of the fact that `viewkeys` on the `dictionary` returns a `set`-like object. For large lists, this offers performance advantages.

```
sum(p[x] for x in p.viewkeys() & q)
```