# understanding python code ----- objs = ((v[i], w[i]) for i in idxs[m:])

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
n = 4
v = [16, 19, 23, 28]
w = [2, 3, 4, 5]

idxs = list(range(n))
idxs.sort(key=lambda i: v[i]/w[i], reverse=True)  

objs = ((v[i], w[i]) for i in idxs[m:]) 
for av, aw in objs:
    print av
    print aw
```

I came across the above chunk of code. If m=2, it returns 23  4  28  5. I wonder how does the below indicated line of code work in Python, is this a function call? or what?. Would you point me to Python 2.7 manual which explain this feature? I'd properly need a better title for this question, but I don't know how to name it, any suggestion?

```
objs = ((v[i], w[i]) for i in idxs[m:])
```

Comment: That is a generator comprehension

Comment: The code is a bit inefficient, as it loops over the integers more than once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a [generator expression](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/), also sometimes called a [generator comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364802/generator-comprehension). The last four lines of code are basically equivalent to

```
for i in idxs[m:]:
    av, aw = v[i], w[i]
    print av
    print aw
```

Comment: awesome, I can understand this chunk of code in 1s! Thanks for the link!

Comment: PEP calls them [`generator expressions`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/)

Comment: @ovgolovin: Thanks for the tip! Linked to both that and the SO question