# Multiprocessing pool 'apply_async' only seems to call function once

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, threadpool

I've been following the docs to try to understand multiprocessing pools. I came up with this:

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(a):
    print 'f(' + str(a) + ')'
    return True

t = time.time()
pool = Pool(processes=10)
result = pool.apply_async(f, (1,))
print result.get()
pool.close()
print ' [i] Time elapsed ' + str(time.time() - t)
```

I'm trying to use 10 processes to evaluate the function `f(a)`. I've put a print statement in `f`.

This is the output I'm getting:

```
$ python pooltest.py 
f(1)
True
 [i] Time elapsed 0.0270888805389
```

It appears to me that the function `f` is only getting evaluated once.

I'm likely not using the right method but the end result I'm looking for is to run `f` with 10 processes simultaneously, and get the result returned by each one of those process. So I would end with a list of 10 results (which may or may not be identical).

The docs on multiprocessing are quite confusing and it's not trivial to figure out which approach I should be taking and it seems to me that `f` should be run 10 times in the example I provided above.

Comment: apply_async isn't meant to launch *multiple* processes;  it's just meant to call the function with the arguments in one of the processes of the pool. You'll need to make 10 calls if you want the function to be called 10 times.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Understood, thanks for the clarification. Would the best method be to `for` loop 10 calls or is there a more appropriate tool in the `multiprocessing` module for what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: Do you want to call the function with the same args each time?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Yes it's 10 times the same args. The function depends on other vars fetched from the net so result may be different each time.

Comment: Ah, so you've got different functions each time?  Then you essentially have a list of functions, and you're calling "apply this function" a bunch of times.  OK

Answer (score 12, accepted):

apply_async isn't meant to launch *multiple* processes;  it's just meant to call the function with the arguments in one of the processes of the pool. You'll need to make 10 calls if you want the function to be called 10 times.

First, note the docs on [`apply()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.apply) (emphasis added):

> ```
> apply(func[, args[, kwds]])
> ```
>
> Call func with arguments args and keyword arguments kwds. It blocks
>   until the result is ready. Given this blocks, apply_async() is better
>   suited for performing work in parallel. **Additionally, func is only
>   executed in one of the workers of the pool.**

Now, in the docs for [`apply_async()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.apply_async):

> ```
> apply_async(func[, args[, kwds[, callback[, error_callback]]]])
> ```
>
> A variant of the apply() method which returns a result object.

The difference between the two is just that apply_async returns immediately.  You can use `map()` to call a function multiple times, though if you're calling with the same inputs, then it's a little redudant to create the list of *the same* argument just to have a sequence of the right length.

However, if you're calling different functions with the *same* input, then you're really just calling a higher order function, and you could do it with `map` or [`map_async()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map_async) like this:

```
multiprocessing.map(lambda f: f(1), functions)
```

except that lambda functions aren't pickleable, so you'd need to use a defined function (see [How to let Pool.map take a lambda function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4827432/1281433)).  You can actually use the builtin `apply()` (not the multiprocessing one) (although it's deprecated):

```
multiprocessing.map(apply,[(f,1) for f in functions])
```

It's easy enough to write your own, too:

```
def apply_(f,*args,**kwargs):
  return f(*args,**kwargs)

multiprocessing.map(apply_,[(f,1) for f in functions])
```

Comment: Careful, I don't think that `lambda` works as lambda functions aren't pickleable (IIRC).

Comment: I understand how `apply` works now and it makes since, but you were right the first time. I'm trying to run 10 times to *same* function with the *same* argument (although the result may not always be the same for other reasons). I would like to end up with a list of the 10 results. Is the best way to do this with a `for` loop then?

Comment: @Juicy I think **map** is what you'd want

Comment: But `map` seems to only take an `iterable`, I guess I should just make an iterable list with 10 times the same argument then.

Comment: @Juicy See my update; you have a list of *functions*;  that's the iterable that you should pass in.  The function that you're mapping should *call* its argument with the arglist

Comment: @mgilson Right;  I've updated to say that it'd be nice to use, but doesn't actually work. Using a defined function should, though.

Answer (score 3):

Each time you write `pool.apply_async(...)` it will delegate that function call to one of the processes that was started in the pool.  If you want to call the function in multiple processes, you need to issue multiple `pool.apply_async` calls.

Note, there also exists a [`pool.map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map) (and [`pool.map_async`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map_async)) function which will take a function and an iterable of inputs:

```
inputs = range(30)
results = pool.map(f, inputs)
```

These functions will apply the function to each input in the `inputs` iterable.  It attempts to put "batches" into the pool so that the load gets balanced fairly evenly among all the processes in the pool.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run a single piece of code in ten processes, each of which then exits, a `Pool` of ten processes is probably not the right thing to use.

Instead, create ten `Process`es to run the code:

```
processes = []

for _ in range(10):
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=f, args=(1,))
    p.start()
    processes.append(p)

for p in processes:
    p.join()
```

The `multiprocessing.Pool` class is designed to handle situations where the number of processes and the number of jobs are unrelated. Often the number of processes is selected to be the number of CPU cores you have, while the number of jobs is much larger. Thanks!

Comment: OP wants a returned result which your example doesn't provide.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't committed to Pool for any particular reason, I've written a function around multiprocessing.Process that will probably do the trick for you. It's posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23119382/how-can-i-multithread-a-function-that-reads-a-list-of-objects-in-python-astroph/23436094#23436094), but I'd be happy to upload the most recent version to github if you want it.