# implementation of python multiprocessing module

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am using a machine learning algorithm (SVM) to perform a classification on a satellite image. The image I am using is 7GB. So, I need to use the `multiprocessing` python module to speed up the computation time. I have read all the posts in `Stack Overflow` as well as the documentation of `multiprocessing` module about how to use it. What I found out wa that my code got really slow after using the `pool` method. Obviously, I do something really wrong and I have no idea what it is. Below, I have the code using `multiprocessing`.

```
img = '/home/SVM_seaIce_types/subset_of_subset_calibration_201605_Polar_stereographic_ratio.tif' 

def predict():

new_shape = (img.shape[0] * img.shape[1], img.shape[2]-2 )

#reshape the image from 3d to 2d in order to use it for classification
img_as_array = img[:, :, 2:].reshape(new_shape)
print('Reshaped from {o} to {n}'.format(o=img.shape,
                                        n=img_as_array.shape))

# Now predict for each pixel
class_prediction = svm.predict(img_as_array)

# Reshape the image and produce the classification map
class_prediction = class_prediction.reshape(img[:, :, 0].shape)
return class_prediction

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()

    pool = Pool(processes=5)
    result = pool.apply_async(predict) 
    print result.get()

    end = time.time()
    print 'the processing time is',(end - start)
```

[image]

Below is the code without using multiprocessing

```
img = '/home/SVM_seaIce_types/subset_of_subset_calibration_201605_Polar_stereographic_ratio.tif' 
start = time.time()

new_shape = (img.shape[0] * img.shape[1], img.shape[2]-2 )

img_as_array = img[:, :, 2:].reshape(new_shape)
print('Reshaped from {o} to {n}'.format(o=img.shape,
                                    n=img_as_array.shape))

# Now predict for each pixel
class_prediction = svm.predict(img_as_array)

# Reshape our classification map
class_prediction = class_prediction.reshape(img[:, :, 0].shape)

print class_prediction

end = time.time()
print 'the processing time is:', end - start
```

[image]

By looking at the processing time, we see big difference. I do not understand what is going on. I may have not understood well how `multiprocessing` module works. That's why I need your help.

By the way, the array filled with the number 1 corresponds to a class 1 after my model's prediction.

I am doing some editing to my post after getting some useful feedbacks:

Thank you everyone for your responses on my problem. I followed the commends you have made and changed my code accordingly. Now I can see my code running faster after using multiprocessing module properly. The problem now is that I do not get the results I am expecting. Here is my code

```
img = '/home/john/desktop/seaIce.tif' #shape of image: 500 x 500 x 5    (row,cols,bands)

#reshape image 3d(rows x columns x number of bands) into 2d (total size  x    number of bands)
image = (img.shape[0] * img.shape[1], img.shape[2]-2 )
tfs2d = img[:, :, 2:].reshape(image)

#find data without nan values 
gpi = np.isfinite(tfs2d.sum(axis=0))
tfsgood = tfs2d[gpi, :]

#use svm model to clasify our image
def predict_class(input_data):
    prediction = svm.predict(input_data)
    return prediction


def main():
    #slice the image into chunks
    chunk_size=100    
    chunks = [tfsgood[i:i+chunk_size, :]
      for i in xrange(0, tfsgood.shape[0], chunk_size)]

    #use multiprocessing module
    pool = Pool(6)
    svm_labelsgood = pool.map(predict_class, chunks)

    # join the results
    svm_labelsgood = np.dstack(svm_labelsgood)
    svmlabelsall = np.zeros(tfs2d.shape[0])
    svmlabelsall[gpi] = svm_labelsgood

    #reshape the image so we can display it with matplotlib
    reshape = svmlabelsall.reshape(img.shape[0], img.shape[1])
    print img.shape
    print reshape.shape


    plt.imshow(reshape)
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The classification image I get is this:

[image]

Instead of getting this:

[image]

The image on the bottom is the final classification image consisted of 3 classes (sea ice types). The thing is that I cannot wait 10 hours until I get the classification results. What do I do wrong when applying the `multiprocessing` module? I am staring at my code for hours and cannot understand why I get a blue image.

Comment: You can't just throw multiprocessing at a chunk of code and have it process things faster. When you use multiprocessing you need to split up a big problem into smaller problems then send each process a different smaller problem. Once each process finishes their own separate problem they have to combine their results to get the complete results from the big problem. I don't know how your libraries work, but my guess is that your multiprocessing is running the same problem over and over on each process.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28420560/multiprocessing-pool-apply-async-only-seems-to-call-function-once

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am trying to classify an image. There are 4 different classes I want to classify. 1st class is grass, 2nd lass is building, roads and rivers. I give data to my model and it tries to predict the correct class. The way it works, it goes through the image and tries to predict each pixel to which class it belongs. To go through the whole image it takes crazy amount of time. I am wondering how I am going to split up the process into smaller chunks as you have mentioned.

Comment: Read about https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#examples. The second example **Using Pool**. You are missing the `TASK` part.

Comment: cool, thanks. I will take a look at it

Comment: I do not see so much potential for multiprocessing. The SVM needs the full dataset to do the clustering. So you cannot do it pixel by pixel. However, you could split your dataset into subsets/slices. Perform a clustering of each subset and combine the clusters afterwards.

Comment: Are you trying to perform supervised or unsupervised pixel classification?

Comment: HI Tonechas, I am performing a supervise classification (Support Vector Machine classifier)