# Sum of product of combinations in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, functional-programming

What is the Pythonic way of summing the product of all combinations in a given list, such as:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
--> (1 * 2) + (1 * 3) + (1 * 4) + (2 * 3) + (2 * 4) + (3 * 4) = 35
```

(For this example I have taken all the two-element combinations, but it could have been different.)

Comment: do the combinations have to consist of 2 elements?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `itertools.combinations`

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> sum([i*j for i,j in list(itertools.combinations(l, 2))])
35
```

Comment: I cannot decide which answer to choose as “the answer”. Is Kevin’s approach superior in any way? (Perhaps in a more general setting or whatever.)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `sum([i*j for i,j in list(combinations(l, 2))])`?

Comment: @blackened: If I was you, I'd accept Avinash's answer, since he's answer is clear and simple than mine. I think my answer was just used more function instead of `*` operator, it doesn't faster than Avinash, but more complex.

Comment: @JoeR: Nope, no need create another list here.

Comment: @kevin  previous code of mine is fater than the current one. Since I heared that, gen expresion takes more no of loops than list.

Comment: @KevinGuan I am not talking about the list, I mean taking out the `itertools.` and just use `combinations(l, 2)` like so: `sum(i*j for i, j in combinations(l, 2))`

Comment: @JoeR then the import stmt should look like `from itertools import combinations`, but it isn't an issue..

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Well, I don't know that :(. However I tested and rollbacked, I'll go to search about it.

Comment: @AvinashRaj yes! That's how I imported it. My bad!

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4]    
>>> import operator
>>> import itertools
>>> sum(itertools.starmap(operator.mul, itertools.combinations(l, 2)))
35
```

[`itertools.combinations(a, 2)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) returns:

```
>>> list(itertools.combinations(a, 2))
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)]
>>>
```

And [`itertools.starmap()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) does:

> Make an iterator that computes the function using arguments obtained from the iterable. Used instead of `map()` when argument parameters are already grouped in tuples from a single iterable (the data has been “pre-zipped”).

Finally, use [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum)  with a [**generator comprehension**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364802/generator-comprehension) to get the final results.

Comment: You can also use `itertools.starmap` in place of `reduce`: `sum(itertools.starmap(operator.mul, itertools.combinations(l, 2)))`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about the pythonic way, but you could resolve this problem into a simpler one.

E.g. For a list [a, b, c] => result can also be written as

```
( (a + b + c)^2 - (a^2 + b^2 + c^2) ) / 2
```

So, it can be written as difference of square of sum of list and sum of squares of list, divided by 2.

You can achieve the same as follows in python:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
( (sum(a) ** 2) - sum([x ** 2 for x in a]) ) / 2
```

P.S. I know the problem can be solved using itertools and question specifically asks for pythonic way to solve it. I think it would be much easy to do it without trying out all combinations.

Answer (score 1):

This is also the sum of the upper triangle of the outer vector product of the array with itself:

```
import numpy as np
np.triu(np.outer([1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]),1).sum()
35
```

Step by step it works like this:

```
# outer product
np.outer([1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4])

array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 2,  4,  6,  8],
       [ 3,  6,  9, 12],
       [ 4,  8, 12, 16]])

# upper triangle
np.triu(np.outer([1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]),1)

array([[ 0,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 0,  0,  6,  8],
       [ 0,  0,  0, 12],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0]])

# then the sum, which is the non-zero elements
np.triu(np.outer([1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]),1).sum()
35
```