# Django ORM for given group by SQL query with aggregation method sum and count

Tags: python, django

I have below given Django model

```
class ABC(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(DEF)
    name = models.CharField()
    phone_num = models.CharField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    amount = models.IntegerField()
```

I want to perform below query using Django ORM.

```
select *, sum(amount), count(date) from ABC group by phone_num;
```

I tried code below, but it does not work.

```
ABC.objects.all().annotate(count = Count("phone_num")).order_by("phone_num")
```

Comment: does your select work when you executing it directly in your sql studio ?

Comment: @AndriyIvaneyko update query.

Comment: Do you need that that `*`? I mean, what exactly fields from the query you're intending to use?

Comment: yes, I need * in query, I am unable to product Django ORM for above sql query.

Comment: The closest ORM analogue I can imagine is `ABC.objects.annotate(Sum('amount'), Count(date)).values('phone_num', 'amount__sum', 'date__count')`, but I'm not really sure what we should do with other fields. Show the last one in group? A first one? It looks really strange to me.

Comment: @Pramod Could you describe in words (without sql or python  examples) what data you want to collect?

Comment: @AndriyIvaneyko I am interested in id, user, name, phone_num, date, amount.

Comment: what count(date) means and supposes to return and what that exprassion means?

Comment: @AndriyIvaneyko, date is just example here, it is fetching number of rows for each unique phone number.

Comment: The solution proposed by @AlexMorozov is the one that will do the job. In order to get the other fields, you just need to iterate over the queryset, and, for each `phone_num`, fetch the corresponding `ABC` objects (which may be more than one)

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini Instead of iterating the code to fetch data for each field, It is better to use raw SQL. I just want my code to be django ORM compliant.

Comment: @Pramod: then go with raw SQL. What you want can't be done with the ORM, and this is a known limitation

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether it possible to grub data you mentioned above ( `Select *, sum(amount), count( date )` by simple order by, probab;y that's `JOIN` query, at least you could try variants below and perform some intersection by `phone_num` on ABC.all():

```
ABC.objects.values("phone_num").order_by().annotate(count = Count("date"), amount= Sum("amount"))
```

Notes:

- values('phone_num') - for  GROUP BY 'phone_num' clause.
- order_by() - for exclusion possible default ordering which ( you could remove that `order_by()`.

**p.s.**
Also try to run query below:

```
ABC.objects.all().values("phone_num").annotate(count = Count("date"), amount= Sum("amount"))
```

**Update**

You could do next loop to grub desired data as **Django ORM** solution is **absent**:

```
data = (dict(o, data=ABC.objects.filter(phone_num=o['phone_num'])[:1][0]) for o in ABC.objects
    .values("phone_num")
    .order_by()
    .annotate(count = Count("date"), amount= Sum("amount")).all())
// know you could access your data in next way:
for item in data:
    phone_num = item['phone_num']
    count = item['count']
    amount = item['amount']
    id = item['data'].id
    name = item['data'].name
    // Do other staff...
```

**Note**
    `data` formed with [generator expression(comprehension)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364802/generator-comprehension)

Comment: This will only fetch phone_num from the table, I need to fetch all fields, any idea on that.

Comment: I have updated answer, idea-- you need equvalent of join on itself.