# How can I optimize this code? And how to optimize Python for loops in general?

Tags: python, arrays, optimization, multidimensional-array

I'm currently running this code:

```
for dicword in dictionary:
    for line in train:
        for word in line:
            if dicword == word:
                pWord[i] = pWord[i] + 1
    i = i + 1
```

Where dictionary and pWord are a 1D lists of the same size, and train is a 2D list.

Both dictionary and train are very large, and the code executes slowly.

How can I optimize this particular piece of code and code like this in general?

**Edit**:
`train` is a list containing about 2000 lists, which in turn each contains individual words pulled from a document.
`dictionary` was created by pulling each unique word from all of train.

Here is the creation of dictionary:

```
dictionary = []
for line in train:
    for word in line:
        if word not in dictionary:
            dictionary.append(word)
```

Edit 2:
Sample of the content in each list:

```
[ ... , 'It', 'ran', 'at', 'the', 'same', 'time', 'as', 'some', 'other', 'programs', 'about', ...]
```

Comment: This really depends on your actual data, can you expand on what the actual data is?

Comment: Is every `word` in the `line` of the list `train` a potential `dicword` in `dictionary`? We need more information about the lists you are going through.

Comment: added the edits to make this more clear,  though it sounds like you're right about the format aug.  When I refer to the words i mean just a string with no spaces

Comment: Where is your list sample?

Comment: An example with three words from your dictionary would greatly improve the quality of the resonses.

Comment: Step 1: Make `dictionary` a set instead of a list.  Step 2: Eliminate the outermost loop in the first code sample and just use `if word in dictionary`.

Comment: Updated as per your recommendations, MLSC and Alexander

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects).

```
from collections import Counter

train = [["big", "long", "list", "of", "big", "words"], 
         ["small", "short", "list", "of", "short", "words"]]

c = Counter(word for line in train for word in line)

>>> c
Counter({'big': 2,
         'list': 2,
         'long': 1,
         'of': 2,
         'short': 2,
         'small': 1,
         'words': 2})
```

Note that the counter itself is constructed using a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions) (aka [generator comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364802/generator-comprehension)).

Also note that you don't even need to create a dictionary.  It is created for you via `Counter`.

You can then use a dictionary comprehension to get the most common words, e.g. top 5:

```
>>> {word: count for word, count in c.most_common(5)}
{'big': 2, 'list': 2, 'of': 2, 'short': 2, 'words': 2}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, for this project I can't import any extra code, I have to code it all with base Python..

Comment: Counter is part of the Python standard library (see link in post).  Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

> optimize Python for loops in general?

A good strategy for helping out with processing lists of very many elements is to use generators ([see also python docs on generators](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generators)).  If you're streaming through a large list, transforming the elements or aggregating them, you may not need them all in memory at a given time.