# Removing Punctuation from a String

Tags: python, string, punctuation

How do I remove punctuation from a string in python? I followed the approach that someone posted on Stackoverflow, but it is not working.

```
punctuation = ['(', ')', '?', ':', ':', ',', '.', '!', '/', '"', "'"]

str = input("Hi, my name is Yael Shapiro!")

for i in punctuation:
    str = str.replace(i,"")

print(str)
```

Comment: *"not working"* is a completely useless problem description

Comment: Also, do not use built-ins as variable names. `str` is a built-in, and you will certainly run in to problems shadowing built-in names.

Answer (score 1):

I find using a combination of [gencomp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364802/generator-comprehension) and `"".join()` works well:

```
>>> import string
>>> s = "Does this string. Have punctuation?"
>>> 
>>> "".join((char for char in s if char not in string.punctuation))
'Does this string Have punctuation'
>>>
```

And as a side note, do not use `str` as an identifier as it [already has a meaning in the Python language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str#str).

The reason that your code is not working, is probably because you're misunderstanding what `input()` does. `input()` simply gets input from the user and returns the input. It looks to me that all you want to do is have a string, in which just do: `sstr = "Hi, my name is Yael Shapiro!"`

Comment: Thanks so much! So I am changing it to the following, but it is still not removing the punctuation:  

import string
sstr = "Hi, my name is Yael Shapiro!"

"".join((char for char in sstr if char not in string.punctuation))
print(sstr)

Comment: You need to assign the value of `sstr` to your stripped string. In other words, use `sstr = ".join((char for char in sstr if char not in string.punctuation)) ` instead of `".join((char for char in sstr if char not in string.punctuation)) `.