# Does sum() function add up values?

Tags: python

There is this "Don't give me five!" kata on codewars. (https://www.codewars.com/kata/dont-give-me-five/train/python).

Here's what you gotta do: "In this kata you get the start number and the end number of a region and should return the count of all numbers except numbers with a 5 in it. The start and the end number are both inclusive!".

I've solved it in an ugly way, which I'm not posting here. What I'm showing is the solution of one of the users. It looks smooth, but I do not understand why it works.

```
def dont_give_me_five(start,end):
    return sum('5' not in str(i) for i in range(start, end + 1))
```

I always thought that `sum()` sums the values, not the indexes. And if I'm right, "i" should be a value, not an index. But if it is, why does this solution work?

Comment: "What I'm showing is the solution of one of the users." - Why don't you ask that user?

Comment: `sum` sums whatever is inside, it doesn't  transform indices into values or anything magical. Try `print(['5' not in str(i) for i in range(start, end + 1)])`.

Comment: You need to `sum(i for i in range(start, end + 1))` and filter `if '5' not in str(i)`. See [generator comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364802/generator-comprehension).

Comment: Thx for help, guys. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sum()` *is* adding the values, those produced by a *generator expression*. And those values happen to be booleans, so `True` and `False`. In Python, the `bool` type is a subclass of `int` and `False` has an integer value of `0`, `True` an integer value of 1.

The expression that produces the boolean values is `'5' not in str(i)`, which is evaluated for each of the iterations of the `for i in range(start, end + 1)` loop. So for every `i` in the range from `start` to `end` inclusive, it counts the number of those values that do not have the digit `5` in them:

```
>>> for i in range(495, 502):
...     print('{:2d} -> {} == {}'.format(i, '5' not in str(i), int('5' not in str(i))))
...
495 -> False == 0
496 -> True == 1
497 -> True == 1
498 -> True == 1
499 -> True == 1
500 -> False == 0
501 -> False == 0
>>> sum('5' not in str(i) for i in range(495, 502))
4
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Now it makes sense! :)))