# Use a while loop to keep count of even integers that a user inputs into a list?

Tags: python

```
myList = []


size = int(input("How many integers do you want in your list? "))
for list in range(size):
    element = int(input("Enter an integer to add to your list: "))
    myList.append(element)
print(myList)

#a function that keeps count of all even integers using while loop
def count_evens_while(alist):
    evenIntegers = 0
    while range <= size:
        for element in range(size):
            if element % 2 == 0:
                evenIntegers = evenIntegers + 1
    print(evenIntegers)
```

This is what I have so far. I can't figure out what I need to do! (I'm a beginner, so sorry if this question seems so simple/easy to fix)

Comment: Can you please state what specifically is not working?

Comment: do you have to use a while loop ? a for loop alone is much easier

Comment: I am doing an assignment that requires me to use different kinds of loops. I already have a working for loop function, but I can't figure out how to make a while loop work in this situation.

Comment: The while loop (calculating the number of even numbers and printing that value) isn't working.

Comment: You can't use `range` as variable name in `while range <= size`

Comment: the while loop needs to test a variable that could change during each loop (basically True or False), or it needs a break condition, otherwise you can't stop it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem

You have several problems here:

- You  never define `size` in the head of the `while` loop.
- You're using the `range` builtin class as an integer value which doesn't make sense.
- You never use `alist` in your function.
- You don't need a `for` loop in your `while` because you are not trying to find the amount of even numbers for each number between `1` to `element`, your trying to find all the even numbers in `alist` (presumably).

Here is what the above fixes would look like:

```
def count_evens_while(alist):
    evenIntegers = 0
    size = 0
    while size < len(alist):
        if alist[size] % 2 == 0:
            evenIntegers = evenIntegers + 1
        size = size + 1
    print(evenIntegers)
```

In the first part of the `while` loop:

```
size < len(alist)
```

We are telling Python to comparse the value of `size` to the length of `alist` each time we loop. We then incrmenet `size` by one each time in the loop:

```
size = size + 1
```

This basically means that each iteration of the loop, the value of `size` will correspond to an index of `alist`. The loop will stop when `size` reaches the last index of `alist`. Here's a visual example to help explain. Assume `alist` is `[1, 2, 3]` and `size` initially equals `0`:

```
First iteration

    alist = [1,   2,   3]
             ^
             |
             +--- size = 0

Second iteration

    alist = [1,   2,   3]
                  ^
                  |
                  +--- size = 1

Third (and last) iteration

    alist = [1,   2,   3]
                       ^
                       |
                       +--- size = 2
```

The next important part:

```
alist[size] % 2 == 0
```

Means we are *indexing* the list `alist`. When you index a list, you use an integer to get a value from the position that the integer corresponds to. In this case, `alist[size]` means that we are getting the value of the integer at position of the value of `size`. The last part:

```
% 2 == 0
```

Means that we are testing if the integer at position `size` in `alist` is even. If it is, we increment the count of even numbers, if not we do nothing.

### Improvements

There are some improvements you can make to your current solution

- Use a `for` loop instead of a `while` loop. It would be the more natural solution here.
- You don't need to do `evenIntegers = evenIntegers + 1`. You an use the increment operator, `+=`, instead.

Here are the improvements from above applied to your code:

```
def count_evens_while(alist):
    evenIntegers = 0
    for element in alist:
        if element % 2 == 0:
            evenIntegers +=  1
    print(evenIntegers)
```

However, this can be improved more! You don't need a `for` loop. You can use a [*generator comprehension*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364802/generator-comprehension) combined with the [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) builtin function to count all of the elements in `alist` that are even:

```
def count_evens_while(alist):
    return sum(1 for el in alist if el % 2)
```

### Stylistic improvements

The last thing I would critique on your code would be to use better variable names. Use names that accurately describe what the variable represents.For example, the variable `myList` would be better renamed to `user_input_numbers`.

Comment: Thank you. I was confused with (while size < len(alist):
        if alist[size] % 2 == 0:) <---- this part of the code. And then I just took off running in all the wrong directions. Also, thanks for the new tricks! Like I said, I am a beginner so I still have a lot to learn.

Comment: Glad I could help you out @Savannah! I'll edit my answer to explain more.

Comment: @SavannahNicole Alright, I edited. See if that helps clarify.

Answer (score 1):

```
def count_evens_while(alist):
    evenIntegers = 0
    idx = 0
    while idx < len(alist):
        if alist[idx] % 2 == 0:
            evenIntegers = evenIntegers + 1
        idx += 1
    print(evenIntegers)
```

Using a for loop would be much simpler though:

```
def count_evens_while(alist):
    evenIntegers = 0
    for el in alist:
        if el % 2 == 0:
            evenIntegers = evenIntegers + 1
    print(evenIntegers)
```

And even simpler using some list comprehension:

```
def count_evens_while(alist):
    evenIntegers = sum(1 for x in alist if (x%2 == 0))
    print(evenIntegers)
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a `while` loop at all:

```
myList = []

size = int(input("How many integers do you want in your list? "))
for list in range(size):
    element = int(input("Enter an integer to add to your list: "))
    myList.append(element)
print(myList)

#a function that keeps count of all even integers using while loop
def count_evens_while(alist):
    evenIntegers = 0
    for element in alist:
        if element % 2 == 0:
            evenIntegers = evenIntegers + 1
    return evenIntegers

print(count_evens_while(myList))
```

If you need to stop a `for` loop early, you can use the `break` statement to break out of the loop. Otherwise, it will stop by itself once it reaches the end of the list. It does not need an ending condition to be given manually.

Comment: I am pretty sure that this is not what is being asked. You need to count the even numbers in the list; not from `0` to `size`.

Comment: Counting the even numbers in the list is exactly what this does... oh, whoops. Right you are. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This is very unlike your program but I hope to teach you something with it... First of all if all you need is to "keep count" you don't really have to save the integers themselves in a list. Which means that all you really need is something like this:

```
count = 0
while True:
    element = int(input("Enter an integer to add to your list: "))
    if element % 2 == 0:
        count += 1 # which is the same as count = count + 1
    elif element == 9999:
        break # user could enter 9999 to exit the loop
    print('I have counted ' + str(count) + ' even numbers so far')
```

I hope in this just to show you that you don't have to complicate simple things

Comment: This is an infinite loop!

Comment: Yes sorry, that was fixed

Comment: IMHO a `try` `except` combo would have been much neater with a termination on non-integer input.

Comment: It would, possibly with a KeyboardInterrupt, but since the OP is a beginner I didn't want to complicate too much